# Shuffle an array, a little bit

Tags: code-golf, array, random, permutations

Given some input array `a = [a1, a2, ..., an]` and a positive integer `k`, shuffle the input array `a` such that no entry is farther than `k` from its initial position.

#### Example

Given the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and `k = 1`, this means the entry `3` can be at following positions:

```
[*, 3, *, *, * ,*] 
[*, *, 3, *, *, *]   (original position)
[*, *, *, 3, *, *]
```

#### Details

- Uniform randomness over all permissible permutations is *not* required, but
- You can assume the input array is limited to the range `[1, n]` (or `[0, n-1]`, where `n` is the length).
- all permissible permutations must have a nonzero probability of occurring.
- Instead of shuffling an input array, you can also just take `k` and the length of the array `n` (or `n+-1` alternatively) as an input, and output a permutation in a suitable encoding (i.e as a list of indices etc). For this you can use 0 or 1 based indexing.
- Instead of `k` you can also take `k-1` or `k+1` as an input if it is more suitable.
- You can assume that `0 < k < [length of array]`.
- Alternatively to sampling one random permutation you can also output *all* permissible permutations.

Comment: Is the input a possible output or do we have to force each element to change?

Comment: @chunes The input *is* a possible output: All permissible permutations must be able to occur!

Comment: If we output all possible permutations, may outputs be repeated?

Comment: We can't guarantee that the input has no duplicates, correct?

Comment: @Steffan "Instead of shuffling an input array, you can also just take `k` and the length of the array as an input, and output a permutation in a suitable encoding", so it's unclear without clarification from OP, but in the meantime you can roll your own duplicate-free input.

Comment: I assume the input-array isn't guaranteed to be a `[1,n]`-ranged list and can basically be any list?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Under the current rules yes it can be arbitrary, but I think we can add this assumption as it leads to no loss of generality.

Comment: @Steffan Yes the input may contain duplicates.

Comment: If the input could contain duplicates, is it at least guaranteed that it's possible to mix them up such that no value is the same?  Consider the trivial example [ 1, 1, 2 ] - No matter how you mix that, one of the values that was 1 in the input will still be 1 in the output.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman That only happens for `k=1`, for `k=2` all permutations are permissible for your example. So to answer your question: we can't guarantee that, actually all entries could be ones.

Comment: Can we take the length of the array, but `-1`?

Comment: @Steffan Yes that is acceptable!

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 47 bytes

```
\(n,k){while(any(abs((a=sample(n))-1:n)>k))0
a}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGSNAUb3aWlJWm6Fjf1YzTydLI1q8szMnNSNRLzKjUSk4o1NBJtixNzC4AieZqauoZWeZp22ZqaBlyJtVBtaokFBTmVGkWpBTmZyYklqRqGBkCgk6ZhpmOoqaljqFOSmJSTqglRvWABhAYA)

Takes the length `n` and the maximum distance allowed `k` and returns a permutation on `1:n` by rejection sampling.

Footer computes 10000 iterations of `f(6,1)` and tabulates the results for each index to give a rough distribution.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>9</s> <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
œʒāα@P
```

1-based input-list, and outputs all possible permutations. Outputting a random one would be 2 bytes longer by adding a trailing `}Ω`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6ORTk440ntvoEPD/f7ShjpGOsY6JjqmOWSyXIQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
œ       # Push a list of permutations of the first (implicit) input-list
 ʒ      # Filter this list of permutations by:
  ā     #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
   α    #  Get the absolute difference between the values at the same positions
    @   #  Check for each whether the second (implicit) input is >= the value
     P  #  Product to check if all are truthy
        # (after which the filtered list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>89</s>  87 bytes

Expects `(array)(k)`.

```javascript
a=>g=k=>a.every((v,i)=>!(1/b[j=i+Math.random()*(k-~k)-k|0])/a[j]&&[b[j]=v],b=[])?b:g(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpLDoIwEADQq9QNmdEBxN/CZPAEnqDpYoCCUKQGSBMT49Wrb/0GCbLUc/9a08k3NrYchcuOHZeS2WDnN0CgHrncQJFXeuB@d5f1kc0yNf4JuAWXfh2m7rM3mIseTJLo/zMcDFWsDd6qawcOY@2nxY82G30HLeiC1IHUkdSJ1JnUxSAUiPEH)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                   // a[] = input array
g = k =>               // k = max. distance
a.every((v, i) =>      // for each value v at position i in a[]:
  !(                   //   abort if:
    1 / b[             //     - b[j] is already defined
      j = i +          //       where j is randomly chosen in
      Math.random() *  //       [i-k .. i+k]
      (k - ~k) - k | 0 //
    ]                  //   or:
  ) / a[j] &&          //     - a[j] is not defined
  [                    //   otherwise:
    b[j] = v           //     set b[j] to v and keep going
  ],                   //
  b = []               //   start with b[] = empty array
) ?                    // end of every; if sucessful:
  b                    //   return b[]
:                      // else:
  g(k)                 //   try again
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>72</s> <s>64</s> <s>63</s> 62 bytes

Lambda that accepts length of array minus one `n-1`, and minimum illegal distance for an element to be moved `k+1`.

```ruby
->n,k{a=*0..n;a.shuffle!.all?{(a.index(_1)-_1).abs<k}||redo;a}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY37XTt8nSyqxNttQz09PKsE_WKM0rT0nJSFfUSc3LsqzUS9TLzUlIrNOINNXWBWC8xqdgmu7ampig1Jd86sRZiyo48W1OubFsjLq6C0pJihbToPF1DnWxtw1iI9IIFEBoA)

*-8 bytes thanks to @Dingus*

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Œ!ạJ{Ṁ<ʋƇ
```

A dyadic Link that accepts the length, `n`, on the left and the minimum illegal distance, `k+1`, on the right and yields a list of all permutations as 1-indexed indices.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//xZIh4bqhSnvhuYA8yovGh////zX/Mw)**

#### How?

```
Œ!ạJ{Ṁ<ʋƇ - Link: n; k+1
Œ!        - all permutations of [1..n]
        Ƈ - filter keep those for which:
       ʋ  -   last four links as a dyad - f(P, k+1):
    {     -     use k+1 with:
   J      -       range of length -> I = [1..k+1]
  ạ       -     P absolute difference I (vectorises) -> distances
     Ṁ    -     maximum
      <   -     is less than k+1?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>104</s> <s>94</s></sup> 92 bytes

### Code

```python
lambda l,k:[p for p in permutations(l)if all(-k<p[i]-i<k for i in l)]
from itertools import*
```

Takes as input:

- The list `[0, 1, ..., n-2, n-1]` where `n` is the length of the list
- `k+1`

Outputs all possible permutations.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY07DsIwEAV7n@KVNjgS4dOgcJKQwohYrLz@yNkUnN4E6J5mRnrlLa@cTs3jhntjFx9PB7bhOhb4XFFACWWucRUnlNOi2ZCHY9ZdGMpIU0dD@KX0TdlMytccQTJXyZkXUCy5yq7xdjEeLHqLo8XJ4mxxmVTYcK/qvKws2/SaLQL26I0qlZLovzLtAw)

### Explanation

- Uses `itertools.permutations` to get all permutations of the list.
- Only adds each one to the output list if `-k<p[i]-i<k` is `True` for every index `i` and value `p[i]` in the permutation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, <s>17</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
ʁṖ'→ƛ←ḟε;G≥
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiIiwiyoHhuZYn4oaSxpvihpDhuJ/OtTtH4omlIiwiO+KBiyIsIjVcbjMiXQ==)

*-4 bytes thanks to emanresu A*

*-1 byte thanks to Aaroneous Miller*

Comment: Nice!  The Both `:` are unnecessary, and you can use [the nameless variable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231288/100664) for -2 bytes. (Or the register)

Comment: FYI, there's a [Vyxal chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106764/vyxal) if you need help with anything, and there's a [deadlineless bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22137/100664) for five Vyxal answers if you want that.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about both, actually.

Comment: You can use the `r` flag for [-1 byte](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiIiwiyoHhuZYn4oaSxpvihpDhuJ/OtTtH4oGw4omlIiwiO+KBiyIsIjVcbjMiXQ==) (Also you need to use `≥` or `≤` at the end instead of `>` or `<`)

Comment: `<` was fine because I was taking `k+1`, but I guess `k` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 178 bytes:

```py
lambda a,k:f([*enumerate(a)],k,a,0,[])
def f(a,k,l,j,c):
 if len(a)==j:yield c;return
 for x,y in a:
  if abs(x-j)<=k and(C:=list.count)(l,y)>C(c,y):yield from f(a,k,l,j+1,c+[y])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc29DoIwFIbhnas4Y6tHo3Ex1bqQeBPIcOhPBEpLSkno1SMmJk7f8uR7x5zewV@uY1yf8rU6GhpNQNgLy6qd8fNgIiXDiNfYI@EJq5oX2liwbFPosEPFRQGtBWf85qTsRG6N06Bu0aQ5@gJsiLBghtYDbfaLqZnYcuj4XfZAXrNSSNdO6ajC7BNnDjN/lExt83uzMQz/6P6Mal/lmq/rBw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
ＮθＦＮ⊞υ⁰Ｗ⊙υ∨⊖№υλ‹θ↔⁻κλＵＭυ‽ＬυＩυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY0xDsIwDEX3niKjIxUJFpZOVVmQWqi4QdoaWpE4bRKDOH1ImPBi6b1v/3FWbrRKx3imlcOFzYAONlkVd@sE/EMpRc9@Bi7FPvn3vGgUUNMnk6uDE44ODVLACRrLFDLXUpaiRe9hK0U9eKs5IHQLsYfnT@cRnVoba4yiKR/d0rYGWqRHSH0pUBW9W9LHRvmQQRXjoTjG3Ut/AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a random permissible permutation. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `k`.

```
ＦＮ⊞υ⁰
```

Input `n` and create an illegal permutation (unless `n=1`, in which case there is only one permutation).

```
Ｗ⊙υ∨⊖№υλ‹θ↔⁻κλ
```

Repeat until the permutation is both legal and permissible...

```
ＵＭυ‽Ｌυ
```

... randomise the permutation.

```
Ｉυ
```

Output the permissible permutation.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 106 bytes

```
from random import*
f=lambda L,k:(shuffle(Z:=L[::])or all([k>abs(s-n)for n,s in zip(L,Z)])and Z or f(L,k))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU87bsMwFNt9CgJdpPR5yBeFAPcEHjvZMQIFiWBVsixI8pBcpUuW5k65TZS0RSeCfATJ93X1p9SP7nL5npIq326fKowDgnSHDHrwY0izQlVWDvuDRE1GsNhPStkja0RVt0J0fAyQ1rLWvMt9ZLF0XGXJUYR2OGvPamp4x3MmGuSLyoLh_Ldxa1BhUWjnp7SzOqZM2zlhQVgSVoQ1YdMVPmiXmGL_PjKvc86LF3xIc4zIDDJCOjwteGwwPx1_390B)

Returns a new list. Requires the input list to be in the format `[1,2,...,n-1,n]` where `n` is the length of the list. Taking `k+1` as an input

Comment: [-5 bytes...](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY87DsIwEET7nGIkGhuWgq9QpHCClFQBhIyIhWXHsWyngKvQ0MCduA3mJ6rV2x3NzF7u7hSPrb1eb12Uw8Wjlr5t4IU9pKEa1_rYz2RhRLM_CJSk83DspDQ1q_KiXOdb3noIY5hein1gYWi5TBtLAcrirBwrqeI8-aFCOsjEmn_DNhoFxpmyros7o0JMuB4RxoQJYUqYEebbzHllI5PsryM9GHGe9bASug5IBBEgLN4SvBroT8bvsSc)

Comment: `k>Z[n]-n>-k for n in L` for -7 bytes if you switch to 0-indexing for `L`

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics math.unicode`, 66 bytes

```
[ iota dup [ v- vabs [ >= ] with ∀ ] 2with filter-permutations ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYwxDsIwEAT7vGI/kEhQUICgRTQ0iCpK4TgXcSKxjX0OoqPknXzEmKSb2V1tr7RYn66X0/m4xZ28oQGjkls10b8JsyxJNKxtR4toO7ZsVJ6wDnCeRF7OsxEEekQymgJ2RbHCJtVgKwpddKgxlZhUGzId9mjw5Pz@/bwzrmfueRDypSM/RlHC1gQ0SathQJV@)

Takes \$k\$ and a length \$l\$ and outputs all zero-indexed sets of indices of length \$l\$ that satisfy the distance constraint given by \$k\$.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) (Lambdabot), 72 bytes

Operator `#` that accepts length of array minus one `n-1`, and minimum illegal distance for an element to be moved `k+1`.

```
n#k=[x|x<-permutations[0..n],all(\y->abs(fromJust(elemIndex y x)-y)<k)x]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNpczcgvyiEgWXxJJEPZ_M4hIuZAHfxMqk1KWlJWm6Fjc98pSzbaMraipsdAtSi3JLSxJLMvPziqMN9PTyYnUSc3I0Yip17RKTijXSivJzvUqLSzRSc1JzPfNSUisUKhUqNHUrNW2yNStioeYp5yZm5inYKqTkcykoFJSWBJcU-eQpqCgUZ-SXAykTBWUFY4jSBQsgNAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
Ṗ'ż-ȧ⁰≤A
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuZYnxbwtyKfigbDiiaRBIiwiIiwiWzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2XVxuMSJd)

Port of 05AB1E.

### How?

```
Ṗ'ż-ȧ⁰≤A
Ṗ        # All permutations of the (implicit) first input
 '       # Filter by:
  ż      #  Length range [1, length]
   -ȧ    #  Absolute differences of values in the same positions
     ⁰≤  #  For each, is it less than or equal to the second input?
       A #  Are they all truth?
```

```