# Return all letter counts as an integer

Tags: code-golf, string, counting

## Definition

Given some string return an integer whose digits are the number ocurrences of a-z (case insensitive, in alphabetical order) in that string. Any character with 0 instances is skipped. Characters with 10 or more instances will define 2 or more digits of the returned integer. For example, aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad (27 a's followed by d) will return 271.

## Input

A single string with one or more letters

## Output

An integer or a string representing an integer

## Test Cases

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| acfzzA | 2112 |
| Hello World! | 1113211 |
| ---!&*#$ | invalid input, any result is acceptable |
| ---!&*#$a | 1 |
| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad | 271 |
| aaaaaaaaaad | 101 |
| cccbba | 123 |
| abbccc | 123 |

This is code-golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins! Standard loopholes and rules apply. Tie goes to first poster.

Comment: Why did you move this from the sandbox so soon?

Comment: @pxeger Honestly I was being Impatient and didn't realize anyone would actually dig through the sandbox. I am noob

Comment: Shouldn't "Hello World!" be  1132111 instead of 1113211, or the order doesn't count?

Comment: Should all invalid inputs have a same, consistent return? Or can invalid inputs return *literally anything*?

Comment: @Kaddath, AFAIR a,d and h are before l in the alphabet.

Comment: @Kaddath The order is alphabetical, so `d=1,e=1,h=1,l=3,o=2,r=1,w=1` → `1113211`

Comment: @pajonk nowhere in the question it is specified that it should be in alphabetical order.. and many answers don't sort the result so it may be a little late to add the restriction now

Comment: @Kaddath the intention was that the result should be specified in alphabetical order. That is what I meant by "a-z" although I should have been more clear

Comment: Suggested test case: `aaaaaaaaaad` -> `101` (which would cause problems for any solution that concatenates the counts and then filters out zeros).

Comment: @DLosc I added a test case for this as well as additional test cases to verify alphabetical order counting

Comment: "case insensitive" is always problematic.  Since this is an English-language site, are we to assume English rules for the case folding?

Comment: @TobySpeight I think you know what I mean. No one else seems to have an issue with it. If you want I can map it out for you: a or A, b or B, c or C, d or D, e or E, f  or F, g or G, h or H, i or I, j  or J, k or K, l or L, m or M, n or N, o or O, p or P, q or Q, r or R, s or S, t or T, u or U, v or V, w or W, x or X, y or Y, z or Z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 44 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 5.5 bytes

```
Ǎ⇩sĠ@ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyI9IiwiIiwix43ih6lzxKBA4bmFIiwiIiwiYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhZCJd)

### Explained

```
Ǎ⇩sĊvtṅ
Ǎ       # keep only letters of the alphabet
 ⇩      # and convert to lowercase
  sĊ    # sort that and get the counts of each letter - this returns [[letter, count of letter] for each letter
    vtṅ # join the counts of letters on ""
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 76 bytes:

```py
lambda x:''.join(str(i)for a in range(97,123)if(i:=x.lower().count(chr(a))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYqxDoIwFEV3v6JEY1@NkCiDSsLg5h@4uDxbKjW1jzxrRH6@MpkweLZ7zu0@saVQ7jtOtr4kj4@rQdFXUhZ3cgGekcEpSyxQuCAYw62Bw2692ZbKWXBV3Ree3g2DKjS9QgTdMqAaSR27cVuQqO0wHKVSs586Nd6TOBN7k01CnufZcjVf4MTif8x4TF8)

Comment: Maybe `int('0'+)` is not necessary to this question?

Comment: @tsh It is if the input does not contain any letters i.e `---!&*#$`. `'0'` pads the result in the event `''.join` returns an empty string.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Inputs without letters are explicitly invalid; I'd assume that erroring falls under "any result". Also note that output doesn't have to be of an actual integer type

Comment: @UnrelatedString Thanks, updated the post

Comment: ([You can also shave a byte off by folding to uppercase.](https://tio.run/##dYq9CsIwFEZ3nyJFMTdiAyKKFjq4@QYuLtf8tJGYhGsLtS8fOwkdPNt3zpc@XRvD/pQo2/qePb4eGtlQcS6f0QV4dwRO2EgMmQuMMDQGjofteSecBVfVg@xTMgRCqtiHDlRLgGIiJ3LTtsBR2XG8cCEWP3U13kd2i@R1MQtlWRbrzXKFM4v/0dMxfwE))

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 64 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,c=65:91/c*s and'%.d'%s.upper().count(chr(c))+f(s,c+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dUzdCoIwGL3fU3zRj5t/8RkVCQbd9QZdxpqKwtrGnEi@vE277sC5OL/m4xqtsmmqC8nfr5JDF4vidMwvuBdhB1yVwTb17NLemMpSlgrdK0dFY6lgLKqpH0TIpqFpZQWYE2iViUH3zkABlg9Pr3vnh52RraMBJFcIGAFjW@Wgpj5mv/7ERT2Ot7mQIWbkXkmp4aGtLFeziYgHH5AkSVa7cL3hi0n4f5TL1xm/)

Comment: That `%.d` is wizardry!

Answer (score 7):

## C, <s>137</s>, <s>124</s>, [90](https://tio.run/##DcrdCsIgGAbg8@6iVeKXfbB@CES6EvFA3qYT1god7CDq0rOdPjzgCNRarNbOPHwaJeg992noJPjYUrESt9hN6H2WROJ7PjmlTHjmxa8XA9atWZZScEK8chqnIJvdvTkUC0fmUyszr8V@s/WrH8LgY6k8/wE), <s>88</s> bytes

Thank you @AnttiP and @tsh for suggestions!

```
s[99];main(c){while(c-10)s[(c=getchar())&~32]++;for(c=64;c-90;)s[++c]&&printf("%d",s[c]);}
```

less golfed version:

```
s[99];

int main(c){
       
    while(c-10)
        s[(c=getchar())&~32]++;

    for(c=64;c-90;)
        s[++c]&&printf("%d",s[c]);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrdCsIgGAbg8@6iVeKXfbB@CES6EvFA3qYT1god7CDq0rOdPjzgCNRarNbOPHwaJeg992noJPjYUrESt9hN6H2WROJ7PjmlTHjmxa8XA9atWZZScEK8chqnIJvdvTkUC0fmUyszr8V@s/WrH8LgY6k8/wE)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! You can convert to uppercase with a bitwise and, saving 13 bytes in the while loop: `while((c=getchar())-10)s[c&95]++;`

Comment: 90 bytes: [`s[99];main(c){while(c-10)s[(c=getchar())&~32]++;for(c=64;c-90;)s[++c]&&printf("%d",s[c]);}`](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7842tIy1jo3MTNPI1mzujwjMydVI1nX0ECzOFoj2TY9tSQ5I7FIQ1NTrc7YKFZb2zotvwgobmZinaxraWANVKWtnRyrplZQlJlXkqahpJqipFMcnRyraV37/38ibpDC9S85LScxvfi/bjkA)

Comment: Thank you all! Really appreciate that! 
AnttiP, thank you for that! I'll take a look on bit wise operations...
@tsh, wow thank you for that! Really insightful! How should I proceed? I saw some people editing their posts to shave some bytes, but it was never that many...

And one final note, I couldn't get it to work on TIO, what does the -w flag do? Just ignores the warnings?

Comment: [Seems to fail the `---!&*#$a` testcase](https://tio.run/##DcvRCsIgFAbg@96iVXLMDqwVgcieZHghf9MJa4UOdhH16Nnuvw8cgFJyp7U1DxcngnwvQxx7Ap9rmTu0oZ8xuERSfC@NVcr4ZyK0t6sB69qsRilYIV4pTrOn6nCvTuuz0nxKYeatOO72bvODH13IhZc/)

Comment: @The Fifth Marshal It does, and that's bad... it exits early thinking * is the new line character... I'll try to solve that...

Comment: @TheFifthMarshal Done! The parenthesis were important...

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
⭆α⪫↨№↥θιχω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaCTqKHjlZ@ZpOCUWp2o455cCJUMLClKLkkH8Qk0dhUwgNjQAEuWamprW//97pObk5OsohOcX5aQocv3XLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 α          Predefined variable uppercase alphabet
⭆           Map over letters and join
    №       Count of
       ι    Current letter in
     ↥      Uppercased
      θ     Input string
   ↨    χ   Convert to base 10
  ⪫      ω  Join digits together
```

Charcoal's arbitrary base conversion returns an empty list for an input of zero, which is the easiest way to map zero to an empty string.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>78</s> 69 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 62 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with `\`.

*Edit: -9 bytes inspired by [@Giuseppe's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238567/55372).*

```r
function(s)cat(table(utf8ToInt(gsub("[^a-z]","",tolower(s)))),sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY49D4IwFEVn@RXlYUwxZagOujC46W7i4EfyKK1p0rSEthr58whsJHrXe3LubXtV9ipaEbSz1OcCAw1YGUljUPuzO9lAnz5WFK4PLLo7MAAWnHFv2Q74EOZlUwLkvaKAQnXdAfJsseF8k4wyuFnIk6E7SmMcubjW1OlIcM63AzWHiqJIV@tsOQLavtDommjbxMAI2g9ppY8mEO0JCiGb6ehvAU4T8w7/p54@73j/BQ)

Prints the resulting number like in [@Giuseppe's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238567/55372).

Comment: Ah, I should have suggested the `cat` here especially since the `tabulate` is longer now!

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```
""&@@@Array[ToString/@Counts@LetterNumber@#,26]<>""&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X0lJzcHBwbGoKLEyOiQ/uKQoMy9d38E5vzSvpNjBJ7WkJLXIrzQ3KbXIQVnHyCzWxg6o4X8AUFVJtLKuXZqDc0ZiUWIyUFWxg3KsWl1wcmJeXTWXUmJyWlWVo5IOl5JHak5OvkJ4flFOiiKIr6urq6impaySCOIk4gYpSly1/wE)

```
                             LetterNumber@#             a->1,...,z->26, others->0
                      Counts@                           letter counts
      Array[                               ,26]           for a,...,z
""&@@@                                                    (don't include missing letters)
            ToString/@                         <>""     concatenate
```

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 66 bytes

```php
<?=join(count_chars(preg_replace('~\W~','',strtolower($argn)),1));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAt0SRGnroXNGtL3QJQkSyCHdZjW4@vW0GAzKP83TBGaWDJ@bdBUtJIvljJ4@3dV6Ksq1FaCF0ypThhteTbCwdUSndKzUwG2Oqtqsb@wHmE2Jis/w)

A rarely useful builtin function, but it turns out satisfying when it does

Comment: Nine one. I read this and was like "oh yeah, that's `count_chars()`" . There should be something cheaper than `preg_replace()` and `strtolower()` but probably isn't!

Comment: @640KB haven't found shorter yet.. I was also experimenting the other way round to have the alphabetical order, not that far but still longer. If you have an idea with it: `for($c=a;$c!=aa;$c++)($i=count(preg_split("~$c~i",$argn))-1)?$r.=$i:0;echo$r;` for 77 bytes

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 23 bytes

```perl
s/\pl/$\.=s!$&!!gi/ge}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP6YgR18lRs@2WFFFTVExPVM/PbW2@v9/j9ScnHyF8PyinBTFf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

---

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-n`, 23 bytes

```perl
s/\pl/print s!$&!!gi/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP6YgR7@gKDOvRKFYUUVNUTE9Uz899f9/j9ScnHyF8PyinBTFf/kFJZn5ecX/dfMA)

Answer (score 4):

## bash, <del>64</del> 44 bytes

##### Original Solution (64 Bytes)

Fairly simple `tr`-based solution - `bash` probably isn't a good way to make a competitive answer, but I had fun doing it!

```bash
tr [A-Z] [a-z]|tr -dc [a-z]|grep -o .|sort|uniq -c|tr -dc [0-9]
```

Depending on how you want to count characters, it could be more than 64 when including the input to this.  A very simple case would be:

```bash
echo my-input-string|tr [A-Z] [a-z]|tr -dc [a-z]|grep -o .|sort|uniq -c|tr -dc [0-9]
```

which really only adds six characters at best and eight if you have to single-quote the input string.

Explanation:

```bash
tr [A-Z]  [a-z]   # Convert all capitals to lowercase in the input stream
tr -dc [a-z]      # Delete everything that isn't a lowercase letter
grep -o .         # Output every character on its own line
sort | uniq -c    # Get a two-column output of all unique characters and their frequencies
tr -dc [0-9]      # Delete everything that isn't a digit
```

##### 44 Byte Solution (by @Digital Trauma)

```bash
grep -io [a-z]|sort -i|uniq -ci|tr -dc [0-9]
```

Among other improvements, this bash solution utilizes some case-insensitive options for utilities such as `sort` and `uniq`.

Here's @Digital Trauma's [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##dcsxC8IwEAXg/X7FtRYH4cBVnBwEBwdxEakdkku0gdDTtCKE/PcYF3HxTd@D97Qa@/zqnbcYrDJrNAKWe8G6OW4P@3ONCS/5FuwdyQm2imKXRglTqek5uAcSuzQFJMPYLmnV5c8djAw2K77GuIGd9V7wJMGbCoiomi9mzRcK1P8Y@DUza132WhfBGw)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer! I don't remember the rules for I/O most bash answers here use, but the 64 byte one should be fine.

Comment: Instead of the second `tr`, we could get `grep` to select only letters: `tr [A-Z] [a-z]|grep -o '[a-z]'|sort|uniq -c|tr -dc [0-9]` (56 chars).

Comment: You might mention that this is for ASCII and similar codings, where letters are consecutive.  `[a-z]` may mean something different to what you expect!

Comment: 44 bytes: [grep -io \[a-z\]|sort -i|uniq -ci|tr -dc \[0-9\]](https://tio.run/##dcsxC8IwEAXg/X7FtRYH4cBVnBwEBwdxEakdkku0gdDTtCKE/PcYF3HxTd@D97Qa@/zqnbcYrDJrNAKWe8G6OW4P@3ONCS/5FuwdyQm2imKXRglTqek5uAcSuzQFJMPYLmnV5c8djAw2K77GuIGd9V7wJMGbCoiomi9mzRcK1P8Y@DUza132WhfBGw)

Comment: Bash (and zsh) often compare fairly well against other non-golfing languages, though perl often does better [in the hands of an expert](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238558/11259).

Comment: Thanks for the tips TobySpeight/Digital Trauma, editing now for the 44-byte solution

Comment: @DigitalTrauma +1, added your solution to the answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
lDáêS¢J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/x@XwwsOrgg8t8vr/3yM1JydfITy/KCdFEQA)

-2 bytes and fix thanks to @KevinCruijssen and @ovs

Comment: This counts non-alphabetic characters as well and returns in the order of the input string instead of alphabetic order

Comment: Your current program could be `lDÙS¢J` for 6 bytes. And to fix the issue mentioned by @ovs above, you can replace the `Ù` with `áê`: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/x@XwwsOrgg8t8vr/3yM1JydfITy/KCdFEQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpKBrp6BkX/k/x@XwwsOrgg8t8vqv8z8xOa2qypHLIzUnJ18hPL8oJ0WRS1dXV1FNS1kFzkjkSsQNUgA).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen,ovs thanks for the fix

Comment: Actually, it can be [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/x@XwwsOrDi3y@v8/WslDSUcpFYhzoDgfiBWAOBzKLoKKpwCxolIsAA) by removing the `S` and taking the input as a list of characters.

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `spelling`, 56 bytes

```
[ >lower ALPHABET counts values [ present ] map-concat ]
```

The `counts` word postdates Factor build 1525, the one TIO uses, so here's a screenshot of running the above code in build 2101's listener:

[image: A screenshot of running the above code snippet]

### Explanation

```
                        ! "acfzzA"
>lower                  ! "acfzza"
ALPHABET                ! "acfzza" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
counts                  ! { { 97 2 } { 99 1 } { 102 1 } { 122 2 } }
values                  ! { 2 1 1 2 }
[ present ] map-concat  ! "2112"
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 63 bytes

Expects an array of characters.

```javascript
a=>a.map(c=>o[i=parseInt(c,36)]=-~o[i],o=[])|o.slice(10).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYuxCsIwFEV3v8JWkUSahyK4peCmX@AQAn2kaUmJeaUpDkX89ai7ueM55w74xGgmN84iUGtTJxPKGuGBIzOyJuXkiFO0tzAzU53OXEvx/lJdkVSavwiid8ay44HDQC40TTIUInkLnnrWMQUAJZpuWS6l5nz1x16t97S@0@TbItcIIYrdfrPFXID5tb9P@gA)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                // a[] = input array
a.map(c =>          // for each character c in a[]:
  o[                //   update o[]:
    i =             //     let i be the result of
    parseInt(c, 36) //     c parsed in base-36
                    //     which gives 0 to 9 for [0-9],
                    //     10 to 35 for [a-z] and [A-Z]
                    //     and NaN for anything else
                    //     (o[NaN] is not an entry of the array but
                    //     an object property which will be ignored
  ] =               //     by join())
    -~o[i],         //     increment it / set it to 1 if it's undefined
  o = []            //   initialize o[] to an empty array
) |                 // end of map()
o.slice(10)         // ignore the first 10 entries
.join``             // join the remaining ones; undefined values are
                    // coerced to empty strings
```

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>30</s> 28 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
{∾•Fmt¨×⊸/+˝(⥊-⌜"aA")=⌜↕26}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAge+KIvuKAokZtdMKow5fiirgvK8udKOKlivCdlakt4oycImFBIik94oyc4oaVMjZ9Cgo+4ouI4p+cRsKoIOKfqCJhY2Z6ekEiCiJIZWxsbyBXb3JsZCEiCiItLS0hJiojJCIKIi0tLSEmKiMkYSIKImFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWQi4p+p)

`↕26` Range from 0 to 25.
`⥊-⌜"aA"` Differences between each of the characters in the input and a or A.
`=⌜` Equality table between those two vectors.
`+˝` Sum the columns.
`×⊸/` Keep the values with sign 1 (or: remove the zeros)
`∾•Fmt¨` Convert each value to a string and join.

A slightly different approach using *Bins Down* at 29 bytes:

```
{∾•Fmt¨×⊸/»1↓/⁼27↕⊸⍋⥊-⌜"aA"}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAge+KIvuKAokZtdMKow5fiirgvwrsx4oaTL+KBvDI34oaV4oq44o2L4qWK8J2VqS3ijJwiYUEifQoKPuKLiOKfnEbCqCDin6giYWNmenpBIgoiSGVsbG8gV29ybGQhIgoiLS0tISYqIyQiCiItLS0hJiojJGEiCiJhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFkIuKfqQ==)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes but +1 (bug fix) for a net -1 byte, all thanks to Razetime*

```
ṁosLk_f√
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxvxin@z4tEcds/7//@@RmpOTr6MQnl@Uk6IIAA)

Digits are in alphabetical order of each letter.

```
       f√    # filter for only letters,
     k_      # and group letters by lowercase value;
 ṁo          # now map to each group & combine the results:
    L        #  get the length
   s         #  and convert to a string
```

Comment: use `k_` for -2, `dmL` doesn't work since count of any letter can be >10, so `ṁosL` or better equivalent should be there

Comment: @Razetime - double thanks!  And well-spotted for the >10 bug (which worked for the test cases, but it's obvious now you've pointed it out...)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>75</s> 72 bytes

```r
function(s,x=tabulate((y=utf8ToInt(s))%%32*(y>64),26))cat(x[!!x],sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY6xDoIwGIRneYpSxLQEhoJBF0zcdDdxMA6/pU2aNIXQ1gAvj8Bmord@3@Wum2Q1SW@4U40hNu0rBy@vwQlChso7ebw1V@OIpTSOizwhw6nc0zQvKeXgSP8Iw/6ZWtFWGNNJEgxcjuMZ02iTM5YHi4QDTIMZXYTWDbo3na7DRWCMFbP05WRZFu6SaLtwZd6gVY2Uab1LEZgBdcJ67ZCyCDgX7fxVi599WAe@EPxPvf49sOkD)

Prints the result. For invalid input, prints nothing.

-3 bytes thanks to Dominic van Essen.

Test harness taken from [pajonk's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238546/67312).

Comment: [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY6xDoIwGIRneYpSxLQEhoJRF0zcdDdxMA6/pU2aNIXQ1gAvj8BGord@3@WuHWU5Sm@4U7UhNu1KB2@vwQlC@tI7ebrXN@OIpTSOizwh/fmwp5RycKR7hmH3Sq1oSozpKAkGLofhgmm0yRnLg1nCAabBhK5C6xo96lZX4SwwxopJWjlZloW7JNrOXJkPaFUhZRrvUgSmR62wXjukLALORTMd1eJnH5aBFYL/qZa/RzZ@AQ)...

Comment: @Dominicvanessen that would capture the handful of characters between `Z` and `a`, right?

Comment: oh, yeah, sorry, you'll need another ```,26``` then, so actually [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY6xDoIwGIRneYpSxLQEhoJBF0zcdDdxMA6/pU2aNIXQ1gAvj8Bmord@3@Wum2Q1SW@4U40hNu0rBy@vwQlChso7ebw1V@OIpTSOizwhw6nc0zQvKeXgSP8Iw/6ZWtFWGNNJEgxcjuMZ02iTM5YHi4QDTIMZXYTWDbo3na7DRWCMFbP05WRZFu6SaLtwZd6gVY2Uab1LEZgBdcJ67ZCyCDgX7fxVi599WAe@EPxPvf49sOkD) then...

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>56</s> 50 bytes

```
%{-join($_|% T*y|% *g|sort|group|? N* -m \w|% C*)}
```

Input comes from the pipeline.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5NDoIwEIX3nmLAYqGxRA@gxrhxYVyZuFBj@BMwSEkLIUI5OxaJRBfOYjLfe5l5k7Ey4CIKkqRFIudxGgpYAHa8W1Wt8RTwVlkMjownvtYxpVSbkDH6np0OnP/l//pv9DzPdftF11WAR4gHokhyFT98IlujpncWpya6SgMO5Kk6CaVgPJchZ0UmV7AnQB9wLpW1IVbTzmzb/Fywd0Ea5hGdW9KodYwG44SuFwsDpUvo1D66F/WmfQE)

Try it in a PS console:

```
$strings = 'acfzzA', 'Hello World!', '---!&*#$', '---!&*#$a', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad', 'aaaaaaaaaad', 'cccbba', 'abbccc'
$result = $strings |
%{-join($_|% T*y|% *g|sort|group|? N* -m \w|% C*)}
1..($strings.Length-1)|%{"'$($strings[$_])' --> '$($result[$_])'"}
```

*-5 by rearranging the first version `%{-join($_|% T*y|% *g|?{$_-match'\w'}|sort|group|% C*t)}`; moving the "match" filter after the "group" allows the use of the "<Property> <Operator> <Value>" syntax of Where-Object instead of using a FilterScript.*
*-1 by removing the unnecessary "t" from "% C*t"*

### Explanation

**%{...}** "%" is an alias for the cmdlet "ForEach-Object", which accepts input from the pipeline and processes each incoming object inside the ScriptBlock {...}
**-join(...)** Unary operator which will join the all the character counts returned inside the expression
**% T*y** takes the input string and calls its method "ToCharArray()", turning the string into an array of single characters.
**% *g** takes the array of characters and turns them back to single-character strings by invoking ToString() (the only method matching "*g"), because Group-Object is case sensitive for characters, but not for strings.
**sort** is an alias for Sort-Object, which will sort the characters.
**group** is an alias for Group-Object, which will group the characters, and return objects with a Count property for each character; returns GroupInfo objects.
**? N* -m \w** "?" is an alias for "Where-Object", the rest expands to "-Property 'Name' -match '\w'" - this lets only objects pass where the Name property (which contains the grouped character) consists only of word (\w) characters. PS allows for partial named parameters, so -m will be identified as -match.
**% C*** gets the property "Count" (the only one starting with C) of the GroupInfo objects.
All the counts will now be collected and joined to a single string; output is implicit.

### Ungolfed

```
ForEach-Object -Process {
    -join (                                             # Will join the counts of all characters produced inside the brackets into a single string
        $_ |                                            # Input string
            ForEach-Object -MemberName ToCharArray |    # input string to single chars
            ForEach-Object -MemberName ToString |       # input chars to single-char strings
            Sort-Object |
            Group-Object |                              # group same characters
            Where-Object -Property 'Name' -match '\w' | # let only word characters pass ("Name" contains the string/character used to group)
            ForEach-Object -MemberName Count            # get only the count of the grouped objects
    )
}
```

Comment: Your code is a Powershell snippet, not a program or a function. Try save your code to a standalone PS1-file and run it.

Comment: Sorry, but I beg to differ. This is a call of the cmdlet `ForEach-Object` (%), passing a scriptblock to the (unnamed) `-Process` argument. It accepts input either by the named argument `-InputObject`, or through stdin/the pipeline. The lines around the main code above are just eye candy. All that is actually required is piping the value to process to the function: `'acfzzA' | %{...}`, which has the same effect as `%{...} -i 'acfzzA'`. This can be pasted directly into a PS console (which I consider valid, since PS is a Shell, after all), and it will show the result. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes, you are right, of course. The question is How to count bytes of your code for the CodeGolf. If you want to use the "names argument -InputObject" or the constant 'acfzzA' then you need to include to your CodeGolf code.

Comment: Not sure what you're after here, sorry. The function ForEach-Object (aka "%") takes input from stdin, which is a perfectly allowed method. So you take the input, for example 'acfzzA', and pipe it to said function. Why would the input count towards the byte count?  This can be pasted into a PS console as is: `'acfzzA', 'Hello World!' | %{-join($_|% T*y|% *g|?{$_-match'\w'}|sort|group|% C*t)}` Two test cases are piped to the code that processes it, which starts at **%{**.  I don't see any functional difference to, say, the Java or JavaScript solutions here.

Answer (score 3):

## Python3, <s>72</s> <s>70</s> <s>67</s> 87 bytes

```python
lambda x:''.join(map(str,map((x:=x.lower()).count,sorted(filter(str.isalpha,set(x))))))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dYqxDsIgFEV3v6JGIw/TsriYJh3c/AMXl2eBFPMKBDBifx6rg0kHz3KTc49/pcHZw9GHortrIRxvEqvcMibuzlgY0UNMof4s5LbLgtxTBeBc9O5hUx1dSEqCNpRmPafCRCQ/YB1Vgsy/FB@MTaCBYa@n6cQ4X/3UWRG56uICyfXiaJpmvdtvtriw@B85h@UN)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! You can save two bytes by removing the spaces after the commas

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ŒufØAṢŒɠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opNK0wzMcH@5cdHTSyQX/D7drRv7/r56YnFZV5aiuo@4BVJWvEJ5flJOiCOTq6uoqqmkpqyQC2Ym4QYo6AA)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ŒuċⱮØA¹Ƈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opNIj3Y82rjs8w/HQzmPt/w@3a0b@/6@emJxWVeWorqPuAVSWrxCeX5STogjk6urqKqppKaskAtmJuEGKOgA)

Both as full programs, taking advantage of Jelly's automatic smash-printing behavior.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>120</s> <s>84</s> 73 bytes

```
f x=do(v,u)<-zip['a'..'z']['A'..];1:r<-[[1|k<-x,v==k||u==k]];show$sum$1:r
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##DcrNCoUgEEDhV4kQpiCDtqWL3iIQFxMVif2R2R3Cd/e6OXyLs6Kz87bFuGQkp7N4K18K/plLAUJdwwdaQZ@ku6a9BVeqCVZwql4pbQg@VevOreePOb@z9MQdzSGv2xwPW3LEkUbsiYYhj38)

-36 bytes thanks to Unrelated String

-11 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard

Comment: [106 bytes inlining `c` and applying some other small golfs](https://tio.run/##dc4xD4IwFATgnV/xqERAhOhqKInRwcHdgTC8SCkvlpaUJiSE/46wuXjL3bddi8NHKLUs1PXGOrijw@zWovVkWXHGPBnRxcYzFSc@tGYEShIJdj6vXttrgLgsldDStVlDygkbca7jwJmnGYXNg4JmnadliGGWhVNYVUuHpIFDb0k7iKIOe2jikuG7maYrOwJ7rI8MvIxVtb85TVN/f9gFvxs34P/UrIqXLw), [102 converting `g` to a fold](https://tio.run/##dY6xDoIwFAB3v@JRiIAIwZ2SGB0c3B0Iw4tQebG05NGEhPDvKJuLN91t1@H4brVeV@oHyw6u6DC7dMg78nkhKXPJy6nM5djZCShJeKeApLK64ciPhah0a16uyxRp13IkpYkDZ@92arkISlpMkVYhhlkWzmFdrz2SAQkDk3EQRT0OoOJK4FPN81kcQdy@NxYelnXjbZ2mqbc/@MGv4xb4n0bU8foB),

Comment: [84 removing `g` entirely](https://tio.run/##dY2xCsIwFEV3v@IZi2nEBD@gCYgODu4OpcPDpiaYJiUNFIr/Hi04uHime@5yDI5P7VzOth9CTHDGhOJkMK46sLKzLulYqgOrnfaPZMT3kdKzIoVrmHSsCmVfvuI1RSoEnWnTKCVHE6bco/UgYYjWJyjLHgfoWE3w3s3zkeyBXD7tALcQXbtenHO@3u42xe/GRfA/LWlYfgM)

Comment: Wow, that's really impressive.  Thanks for the save!

Comment: [Bonus: 4 bytes longer, but kind of funny](https://tio.run/##dc29DoIwGIXh3av4rI0FY0mcAROjg4O7A2H4Iv0LpSWlCQk3X2Fz8UzvMx2NUy@sTckMow8RHhixuGsMOwmm7jy4ijcMWVGwhbWlWiWNjSJkde1yGv3LzyJU9GraMmIv4KLKSfuZWuFU1KDSgMZBDWMwLkKWDTiCzBuCH7ksN3IG8lz/Pbx9sN1@M@d8fzwd6G/jBvy/jrR5@gI)

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##DclBCoAgEEDRq0QEU6BRew26RTC4mKBIrAjLGMK7m5vPg7/R7ZZ9T2ktWKOP9StCo@RnLwSCtoUPDMKYZYRXEu9wYB@dkixerV2MIdfkN3QmHWRPfXl7PtVaEs0808g8TWX6AQ "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @WheatWizard That's a really efficient solution, but doesn't the problem require the output to be one integer (instead of a list of integers)?  Maybe I missing something, but I think you have to add ">>=show" at the end like Unrelated String did in order to get the correct result (like [this](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwja6qEajTKdU00a3KrMgWj1RXU9PvUo9NlrdEciK1Smy0Y0uLs2NNqzJttGt0Cmztc2uqSkFkrFAOTuDWDs72@KM/PL/uYmZebYFpSXBJUU@eSppSomJSRVJiY4VFRERSv8B)).  Either way, thanks for the saved bytes!

Comment: Ah I misread the question.  In that case [you can save 1 more byte](https://tio.run/##DcrNCoUgEEDhV4kQpiCDtqWL3iIQFxMVif2R2R3Cd/e6OXyLs6Kz87bFuGQkp7N4K18K/plLAUJdwwdaQZ@ku6a9BVeqCVZwql4pbQg@VevOreePOb@z9MQdzSGv2xwPW3LEkUbsiYYhj38 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 64 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.sort().join(o='').replace(/([a-z])\1*/gi,c=>o+=c.length)&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYtBDoIwEADvvkLQQIt2iQ8oiTd/4AE5bEpByKZLWuKhn6/xbuc6Myt@MBi/bLtyPNo06RR0FyCw34WElRcnWNe1BG83QmNFK3pUcZCvW9POy9Xoji/aAFk3729ZVZwMu8BkgXgWk@gBoEQzxXgvBykPf@zDEvHxyZ7GItcopYqqOZ0xF2Ce8fekLw)

Based off Arnauld's answer. Takes input as a character array.

Sort, join, match runs of one character and append that to `o`, and yield that at the end.

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, <s>48</s> 44 bytes

Prompts for string

```
10⊥((+/(48+m)∘.=n)++/(m←17+⍳26)∘.=n←⎕av⍳⎕)~0
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv6HBo66lGhra@homFtq5mo86ZujZ5mlqA/m5IEXm2o96NxuZQcWBIkDtiWVAMSCtWWfwH2gG1/80LvXE5LSqKkd1LiDTIzUnJ18hPL8oJwXM19XVVVTTUlZB4SSCeYm4QYo6AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell)  6+, <s>47</s> 46 bytes

*-1 byte thanks @Julian*

```powershell
-join($args|?{$_-in'a'..'z'}|group{"$_"}|% c*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDPT4MwHMXv/Su62a2w0MWygycjxoueNHLYwRgCpUMWpNhCNPz427EdyKaL7/h57/te8i3EJ5fqjWdZj3bwGjY92Ys0t1AoE9XeNCggaY5DvF7jGndtIkVVNHMUzLt2AdnK7jsAPAsAx8Ih29X1LXawS6mLbYPuda@AWyGzeKYNSulGm4NHCJktVxdI89@AnpHQ3A4o/F@xmb46yxlML0fMGIuiQ527GYNRpOFEgA1buIANgFoozYuq9EuZ5okDEf8qOCt5rN@EgiEguaqyUoOl/p53Ej/YL0/@XaVK8f4Y7fXlqzfUGvkVY1wpUzV2EP5xnJhyzz8DY2wyHsyW4X9HO9D13w)

Comment: This expects an array of characters as input, not "_A single string with one or more letters_".

Comment: Thanks. The CodeGolf allows any [string representation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/whats-a-string). I think it will be useful for you to read the https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [You can drop the last `t`](https://tio.run/##dZDPT4MwHMXv/Su62a2w0MWygycjxoueNHLYwRgCpUMWpNhCNPz427EdyKaL7/h57/te8i3EJ5fqjWdZj3bwGjY92Ys0t1AoE9XeNCggaY5DvF7jGndtIkVVNHMUzLt2AdnK7jsAPAsAx8Ih29X1LXawS6mLbYPuda@AWyGzeKYNSulGm4NHCJktVxdI89@AnpHQ3A4o/F@xmb46yxlML0fMGIuiQ527GYNRpOFEgA1buIANgFoozYuq9EuZ5okDEf8qOCt5rN@EgiEguaqyUoOl/p53Ej/YL0/@XaVK8f4Y7fXlqzfUGvkVY1wpUzV2EP5xnJhyzz8DY2wyHsyW4X9HO9D13w "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 64 bytes

```scala
s=>('A'to'Z').map(c=>s.count(_.toUpper==c)).filter(_>0).mkString
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHdSsMwGL3fU3yrxSaylnW7EMQUhgiCwmBDBG9GmqZSzZrYZDI29uw1bdoqMnMVzm97ohkVtJbpO2cGnrgxvLqTu9Jo4HvDy0zDQik4jkYAX1QAa7kbWJuqKN@AJMMNjrUmCQoWgZHBa4CjLVWIkURHrQdtIiOfleIVIQzjKC@ErUKbZGqVHy6kBjj1RXxPt0pwbYPX/BNZFMCjLD8cFh6ECXizOJ55E4c/cCEkvMhKZGPHxnE8t4peEIbh@PLqwnfkX5R2nh6n/5@sK78@I@64eDpwjLE07dNn88GSppb5gS2Km//OZWWXbiSoKNXOTOwKyr4LzzDchsMkrYIys7Mzke5FnAFb6tRFKLuoEaVbDqDIAfUe8itXe2j5iMFv/c0X@U7lAReaN/T9arVcnVHAmIDfB3ltTds/OtXf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 48 bytes

```ruby
->s{((?A..?Z).map{|c|s.upcase.count(c)}-[0])*''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664WkPD3lFPzz5KUy83saC6JrmmWK@0IDmxOFUvOb80r0QjWbNWN9ogVlNLXb32f4FCWrRSYnJaVZWjUqyygq6dgpGhoREXWNgjNScnXyE8vygnRREqaWhoaAxUAJZX19XVVVTTUlZJVIdKQrQl4gYpMDvMDf8DAA)

Comment: `.count(c)` -> `.count c`

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 168 bytes

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(c,'')WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY
x)FROM(SELECT x,sum(1)c
FROM(SELECT substring(@,number,1)x FROM spt_values WHERE'P'=type)x
GROUP BY x)x WHERE x like'[a-z]'
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1531147/return-all-letter-counts-as-an-integer)**

This will work for input fewer than 2048 characters. The output is ordered according to the position of the letter in the alphabet

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 24 bytes

```
T`Llp`LL_
O`.
(.)\1*
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyTBJ6cgwccnnss/QY9LQ08zxlCLS0VP7f//xOS0qipHLo/UnJx8hfD8opwURS5dXV1FNS1lFTgjkSsRN0gBAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
T`Llp`LL_
```

Uppercase all letters and delete all other printable ASCII.

```
O`.
```

Sort the letters together.

```
(.)\1*
$.&
```

Get the lengths of all the runs.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <strike>94</strike> <strike>91</strike> 84 bytes

```lua
for i=65,90 do _,c=(...):upper():gsub(string.char(i),"")io.write(c~=0 and c or"")end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnBCoMwDADQXwmeUijBi4JCD/uS0aXVBUYr0TLw4K9H3/X9WjRbqoKEcfBTD6nC23NAInJz27as6OZ1bx/cD5WyEn@jojjfdU4q/VWOjHyFHmJJwFD1iVySmUVezvN1Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.7](https://julialang.org), 47 bytes

```
!x=join((c=count.('a':'z',lowercase(x)))[c.>0])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY49TsQwEIVr-xSTBREbJcs6W4CQshIV3IACKCa2I3k1sqPEgSVXoUnBHmpvg1EQouFV8_e9eR_H_UgO5_k4xra8OV1lh3ofnBdC1zqMPq5FjvltPuUFhTfbaxysOEgpn_R6t3mRP9h9G3pw4Dz0Fg05bwchOSRhARZqGDpyUbgCVs9xtWy63vlIXiDUO8hQcuvNYjefPlG303THKqUq_mCJAjyGnkzGlFLbNOVlWWYXl2fnzPlXJGfS726MBaB_TxmGkSK4AVBr20VsyP4CyBTH_2VYdf33wDC1UVxr3TSJrLYcmyZ13-US9gs)

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 49 bytes

```julia
r='a':'z'
!x=join((c=@.sum(in((r-32)r),x))[c.>0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYvNisIwFIXXyVPcOmKToRVvuhCEiO7mDWahLm6TCJGYSlqh9OVrRRA3ntV3/i734An7cUw6p3yTDznPen1pfBTC6N2yvV/Fk1NZKZlk0Ut5MMvt6iTHc5PAg4@QHNngo2uF5DCJCnCgob0F3wlfwOzYzV7NLfnYhSgI9BYyktxFO5I5D8OeKUTF/1wIDfw3KdiMIWI1pbwsy2zx@zNnbyKGnL7LMrX@HFiGK@TGmLqenqriVNeTe@ID)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 23 bytes

```
{,/$#'=x@<x:("a{"')__x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJx9kVFLwzAUhZ/Nr8iy4VpZ1rVFlEZB8UWffBF8GGNL03Qri8lMUuk29Leb0jIcdbsEAt89uZeckyf7UTDoD++rh7sq8RDdo6E/n1ffANhkP5huf3SSQwgrslBr4i1yWghSkS3R/qzWTBFl+W73iAiKwjBCsxo9cyEUfFdaZD3XCMMwds2mhzHuXV71BxARb9Jf+D3PP+IUkRFqtfR0ZfXCm46uxuGkxYyxNKU1ieJWmKYOHggIwMrajUmCgKmML5XIx8ZStuYVW1G55GOmPoLPkhtbKGmCKL69juNAc1tqiakQWHBrucZMldIaTN2RuJCWL7kG4M29g0/UcANe5Ka08AKeqNfSuj5orDwtqx0Gf83tSluvwcHmjqKQX1QUmbvdyhGkcgs1N6WwsDCQMsY3lqaCHybQf5aAc8nACxcMOAKdAZMQNOmc/qyLCDR5ndfU9QuXl7Wz)

- `_x` lowercase the input
- `("a{"')_` drop all non-letter characters
- `x@<x:` sort the characters
- `#'=` build a dictionary mapping the distinct characters to the number of times they appear
- `,/$` convert the counts to strings, then join them (and implicitly return)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
LỊDḳ€c
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPUwlRTElQkIlOEFEJUUxJUI4JUIzJUUyJTgyJUFDYyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PWFjZnp6QS0lM0UlMDklMjIyMTEyJTIyJTBBSGVsbG8lMjBXb3JsZCEtJTNFJTA5JTIyMTExMzIxMSUyMiUwQS0tLSElMjYqJTIzJTI0YS0lM0UlMDklMjIxJTIyJTBBYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhZC0lM0UlMDklMjIyNzElMjIlMEFhYWFhYWFhYWFhZC0lM0UlMDklMjIxMDElMjIlMEFjY2NiYmEtJTNFJTA5JTIyMTIzJTIyJTBBYWJiY2NjLSUzRSUwOSUyMjEyMyUyMiZmbGFncz1KQ2U=)

##### Explanation

```python
LỊDḳ€c  # Implicit input
L       # Lowercase the input
 Ị      # Only keep alphabetic characters
  D     # Duplicate this string
   ḳ    # Sort and uniquify it
    €c  # Count of each character
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>121</s> 118 bytes

```java
s->{var C=new int[91];s.chars().filter(c->(c&95)%91>64).forEach(c->C[c&95]++);for(int c:C)if(c>0)System.out.print(c);}
```

Input as a Stream of character codepoints. Assumes the input only contains printable ASCII.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dZFrVxMxEIa/8yumC5SEsoFytV27XBbkJlWpitoWDdksTUmzdZMWaF3/ek1q4Xj0mA85M3kmk/fNdOmQ@t34bsIk1RouqFDjOQChDM8SyjjUXQowTEUMDHVtORkYIYk2Gac9cqpMYxqBxoGtzOfspg01gkEdFNQm2g/HQ5pBVFP83jVuVsrtQJNESPsGYn6IWLGyhRcr5XB7E5MkzY4o6zgQNR1pl0o4sKfI3gVWjbBIEAvXcONRG94j6cCQfmYZYjjIJ4ET0B/cSCtgpmOqvWedIStVqNtmGyj@bcu1deIM1yaimledxqeqsUdZMhrteyveCZcyhas0k3HBpr7vF4rL8wt/hNTG9P8rthgKLW9@YbG4hPByacUnq2vl9Y3Nre2dF5Vq8LIW7u7tH0SHR6@OT07Pzl9f1N@8fXfZeP/h49Wnz1@arVb7@us3esNintx2RPdO9lTa/55pMxjePzyOxj/yn14@swXwz@c8OSx5VfCmo3JLEfZMCOvQTCP8DP/uIRWasXw66XzyCw)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                        // Method with IntStream parameter and no return-type
  var C=new int[91];        //  Counters-array, starting all at 0
  s.filter(c->(c&95)%91>64) //  Filter the input to only keep letters
   .forEach(c->             //  Loop over each letter-codepoint:
     C[c&95                 //   Convert the codepoint of the char to uppercase
           ]++);            //   And increase the counter of that letter by 1
  for(int c:C)              //  Loop over the counts:
    if(c>0)                 //   If the count is not 0:
      System.out.print(c);} //    Print that count
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 72 bytes:

```py
lambda x:'%.*s'*26%(*(x.lower().count(chr(a//2+97))for a in range(52)),)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYrLDoIwEADvfkWJYnerQILxmXjw5h948bJSKiS1JStG5OcrJxMOznFmmk9bebfaNRzM8RosPW6aRHeQcaqeUuWbGBR0qfXvkgHTwr9cC0XFQFmWL/ZbRONZkKidYHL3EtY54hJDw/UwGpBUmL4/ScTJT51La724eLY6GoUkSaK5ms5oZOk/ehjDFw)

---

Started with [another Python 3 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238536/88225) and ported the string truncation from [this Python 2 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238540/88225).

---

Used `'%.*s'` to convert a number to a string, and truncate it. By passing in the character count twice, it will either produce an empty string or the count as a string.

`'%.*s % (0,0)'` -> `''`

`'%.*s % (1,1)'` -> `'1'`

`'%.*s % (27,27)'` -> `'27'`

This string formatting needs a tuple, so to produce a doubled up tuple (`(10, 20, 30) -> (10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30)`) I doubled the range of numbers and then mapped them back down to the original values.

```
(97, 97, 98, 98, ..., 122, 123) == (a//2 for a in range(97*2, 123*2))
(a//2 for a in range(97*2, 123*2)) == (a//2 for a in range(194, 246))
```

Then make the range start from 0 to save some characters

```
(a//2 for a in range(194,246)) == (a//2+97 for a in range(0,52))
(a//2+97 for a in range(52))   == (a//2+97 for a in range(0,52))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
FI^zNLCa
```

[Replit!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) Or, here's the closest equivalent (10 bytes) in Pip Classic: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/3s0z3s/HOdG36v///x6pOTn5CuH5RTkpigA)

#### Explanation

```
FI^zNLCa
   z      Lowercase alphabet
  ^       Split into a list of characters
    N     For each character, count number of occurrences in
     LCa  First command-line arg, lowercased
FI        Filter (removing zeros)
          The resulting list of numbers is concatenated together and autoprinted
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP5.1 (68 chars)

Given *$argv[1]* as a command line argument, it's using 2 [error control operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) to silence warning :

```php
foreach(range(@A,@Z)as$a)str_ireplace($a,1,$argv[1],$n)+$n&&print$n;
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##dZBRS8MwFIWf21@RzbA22jk7ER/q0L35D4SNMW7T2zVQkpBkUxz@9npbNyaIhb6c75yTw7WN7Z6ebWPZbMYebvOYB/TBswVbx9E6AVmvPlfLJGPJPM/vk03Wq6/Ytoa9GddWox7lhAif6HQ6HU2urzgM6CTC/181tD/@dQ4gvzsDKWVZ/pTOz0ugLEn@pW2KOK73WgZlNKtTDm6nxbGrjUOQTepA7zBdZisBnoPwwW2VQ9uCRPJmeTYEMq7FDdeTiXVKB66L7otaTxWnA4Fn/CCONIIrnTGOHxZlwGpDp@MHVsSRKbc@gAupoE1R9EJrlBZFf@ihl9FvWLmva3Rk4GYfKEupHYatbBF0n4xUzdKBjRaXVwQVVgrTMTpnHHtXoWGDCXR1cY0pT8t7Y2LBe6wSUXTf) - 63 chars

Comment: Still shavable, too many literals in that line.