# Draw a battery indicator

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given the battery level `L` in the range `0-5`, your code should draw the following ASCII art.

When `L=0`:

```
############
#          ###
#          ###
#          ###
############
```

When `L=1`:

```
############
###        ###
###        ###
###        ###
############
```

When `L=2`:

```
############
#####      ###
#####      ###
#####      ###
############
```

And etc. You can change the character `#` to any other (except space), it's up to you. Trailing spaces are allowed.

This is a code-golf challenge so the shortest solution wins.

Comment: I presume I can't change the character `#` to a space.

Comment: @pxeger Yes, you can't now :)

Comment: you allow trailing whitespace, but what about preceding whitespace? (specifically a preceding newline?)

Comment: @Dave I think it would be fine

Answer (score 14):

## Google Sheets, 124 bytes

```
=substitute(query({rept("#",12);sort(if({1;1;1},"#"&rept("#",A1*2)&rept("-",10-A1*2)&"###"));rept("#",12)},,9)," ",char(10))
```

### 89 bytes if it's okay for the output to be displayed in separate cells

```
={rept("#",12);sort(if({1;1;1},"#"&rept("#",A1*2)&rept("-",10-A1*2)&"###"));rept("#",12)}
```

[Try it here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SXPf7wZDsl1N_OzFFD6DDKilnr5chz527Z7B2bhodmg/edit#gid=0)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861), and nice first answer!

Comment: @pxeger, thanks! :)

Answer (score 13):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>266 245</s> 242 bytes

-21 bytes thanks to @emanresu A's suggestion to use `ÿ` instead of `!` (since `ÿ`'s charcode is the same as the glider reference value `255` on an 8 bit bf interpreter like TIO's).

-3 bytes by removing unnecessary code (at the expense of a pretty memory layout).

```
-[-[-<]>>+<]>->>+++++[<++>-]->++++[<...>-]<<.>+>-[>+<-----]>---<,>[<->-]<[<+>-]<[>->+>->+>->+<<<<<<-]+++++[>+>>+>>+<<<<<-]->>>>>>>-<+[[[-<+]-.>+[->+]-<[+[-<+]-..>+[->+]-<-]>+<-<[+[-<+]-<<..>>>+[->+]-<-]+[-<+]-...<.>>+[->+]<->]<<+]++++[>...<-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5dCgIxDIQPFCd4gNCLhDyoIIiwD4Lnr1/bdTf9CZlJMnP/3F7b8/t4967kRLVmfCKNyDBrKrVVuDtVhDfQpFMjaJfi0jI0WGZmYon9X8xQraVg8@4gYjMUlokHKyGQjJUibUdOCEGUDwY7zvTJHhOO0R3HGr6tlv6gVL1ffw)

Uses a glider and fancy loop tricks to print the middle 3 rows. Uses `ÿ` instead of `#` since that is allowed by the challenge.

Ungolfed:

```
memory layout
(pni = 5 minus inp)
3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
' ' \n  ÿ   pni inp pni inp pni inp ÿ

' ' = 32
-[-[-<]>>+<]>-
\n = 10
>>+++++[<++>-]
ÿ = 255
-

print top row of ÿs
>++++[<...>-]<<.>+

get input
>-[>+<-----]>---<,>[<->-]<[<+>-]<

copy to loop cells
[>->+>->+>->+<<<<<<-]
+++++[>+>>+>>+<<<<<-]
create glider refs
->>>>>>>-<+

main loop
[
  glider collision guard
  exit the loop when all loop variables are exhausted
  [-
    print first ÿ
    +[-<+]-.>
    +[->+]-
    print ÿs in battery
    <[
      +[-<+]-..>
      +[->+]-
      <-
    ]
    move glider back one cell
    >+<-
    print spaces in battery
    <[
      +[-<+]-<<..>>>
      +[->+]-
      <-
    ]
    print last 3 ÿs and \n
    +[-<+]-...<.>>
    +[->+]
    move glider back one cell
    <->
  ]<<+
]

print last row of ÿs
++++[>...<-]
```

Comment: Would it be cheaper to use `ÿ` instead?

Comment: It could be, actually. Let me try doing that and see.

Comment: Finally got around to implementing your golf @emanresu A. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 46 bytes

```
lambda n:[s:="#"*12,*3*[f'#{"##"*n:10}###'],s]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY39XISc5NSEhXyrKKLrWyVlJW0DI10tIy1otPUlauVlIH8PCtDg1plZWX1WJ3iWKgurbT8IoU8hcw8haLEvPRUDTNNK63cxAKNgqLMvBKdNI08TU0dMFtDE6JjwQIIDQA)

Outputs a list of lines, as [allowed by standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095).

\$ -9 -1 = -10 \$ thanks to @xnor

---

### [Python](https://www.python.org), 76 bytes

```
lambda n,r=f"#{' '*10}#".replace:[a:=r(" ","#")]+[r(" ","#",2*n)+"##"]*3+[a]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3fXISc5NSEhXydIps05SUq9UV1LUMDWqVlfSKUgtyEpNTraITrWyLNJQUlHSUlJU0Y7Wj4RwdI608TW0lZWWlWC1j7ejEWKiZWmn5RQp5Cpl5CkWJeempGmaaVlq5iQUaBUWZeSU6aRp5mpo6YLaGJkTHggUQGgA)

Did you know Python's `str.replace` method has a third parameter to limit the maximum number of replacements that will be performed? You do now!

Comment: 47 bytes using f-strings: `lambda n:[s:="#"*12]+[f"#{'##'*n:10}###"]*3+[s]`

Comment: List unpacking saves a byte: `lambda n:[s:="#"*12,*[f'#{"##"*n:10}###']*3,s]`

Answer (score 7):

## C (POSIX), 83 bytes

```c
#define s"\n############"
#define r"\n%1$-11s###"
f(i){printf(s r r r s,s+12-i*2);}
```

I was originally tweaking [ErikF's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243364/8927) but ended up making more substantial changes, so it felt like a new separate answer. Note that this saves some space by printing a newline *before* the output, which [has been approved](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243337/draw-a-battery-indicator#comment547981_243337).

Uses compile-time string concatenation to compress the output template, then uses `printf` to fill in the correct amount of the bar.

### Breakdown:

#### `r` template pattern

```
\n             - print a literal newline
  %     s      - followed by a string
   1$          - from the first argument (POSIX extension)
     -         - padded with trailing spaces
      11       - to at least 11 characters
         ###   - followed by 3 literal hash symbols
```

#### `printf` call

```c
printf(
  s r r r s,     // concatenate define'd strings into full pattern
  s + 12 - i * 2 // first argument: fragment of s (last i * 2 + 1 characters)
);
```

#### Expanded

```c
f(i) {
    printf(
        "\n############\n%1$-11s###\n%1$-11s###\n%1$-11s###\n############",
        "\n############" + 12 - i * 2
    );
}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TczBCsIwDAbge58idAqttWB32KX6Jl6kWyUHu9FML6PPXmNFMIGQ/B8k2HsItXbjFDFNQPKaur@S4ieZZe921jlqeVSotyVjWqMiyK3pSMb1Fg@99qUyweOGSb1mHDVsAiDOWX1ivJw84HngYcyXGPmjb9vyXElJ2a4iSn0D)

---

As an interesting alternative, this version uses hex values to draw the shape, so it's limited to `f` characters, but avoids the initial newline. It is the same size (83 bytes):

```c
#define r"%2$-11lxfff\n"
f(i){printf("%lx\n"r r r"%1$lx",(1l<<48)-1,(16l<<i*8)-1);}
```

Comment: Somehow, the "Expanded" version might be less readable than the golfed version. :-)

Comment: yes the golfed version is quite nice for its clarity, but I expanded it so that it is obvious what's happening for people who may not be familiar with C's macro expansion / compile-time string concatenation

Comment: Very elegant.  I was going to take a stab at this one but I don’t think I can outdo this.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
ＵＯ⊕⊗Ｎ³-¹²↘‖Ｏ↓ＵＯ±³-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY0xDoMwEAT7vAJRnSUogC5paSgCET@wnYtBOs7IOjvPdyyFalcz0q7ddLBeU86LIc8OJrYBD2TBN4w@Gio58RlljofBAEqpphqaqm5r9bi9ws4CXV/q0yeE@@i/vO5uk0JW/BBaWRIG0uffFXwdzei0IAzq2sq5z22iHw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＵＯ⊕⊗Ｎ³
```

Draw the fullness of the top half of the battery.

```
-¹²↘
```

Draw the line at the top of the battery and leave the cursor at the top right of the 3×3 square end.

```
‖Ｏ↓
```

Reflect to complete the fullness and sides of the battery. (This also moves the cursor to the bottom right of the 3×3 square end.)

```
ＵＯ±³-
```

Draw the 3×3 square end.

Answer (score 5):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 152 bytes

```
N-46
Count i while i-2 {
Count l while (l-3)*i {
Count c while c-14 {
Write 32+1/((c+3)/2%7/_+1)
}
Write 10
}
Count h while h-12 {
Write 33
}
Write 10
}
```

Uses exclamation points. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/99P18SMyzm/NK9EIVOhPCMzJ1UhU9dIoRoqlgMV08jRNdbUyoSLJ0PFk3UNTYCC4UWZJakKxkbahvoaGsnaxpr6Rqrm@vHahppctVBJQwMgE6I5A6o5Q9fQCKHZGEXp//9GAA)

#### Explanation

This was fun to golf. The verbose syntax of *Acc!!* drove me to combine as many `Count while` and `Write` statements as possible, which required some interesting expressions to encapsulate the logic.

```
N-46
```

Read a character from stdin and store its codepoint minus 46 in the accumulator. If the input number is `L`, the accumulator now holds the value `L+2`.

```
Count i while i-2 {
...
}
```

Do the following twice:

```
Count l while (l-3)*i {
```

Do the following (output the middle part of the battery) three times, but only on the second iteration of the `i` loop:

```
Count c while c-14 {
```

Do the following (output a character in the middle part of the battery) fourteen times:

```
Write 32+1/((c+3)/2%7/_+1)
```

Write either a space or an exclamation point, based on the loop index `c` and the accumulator value `_`.

Observe that we want to output some number of exclamation points, then some number of spaces, then three more exclamation points. This looks like a slice into a periodic function. Since we want to add exclamation points in pairs, let's aim for something like this:

```
0         1
01234567890123456789
!!!!..........!!!!..
```

where `!` means "definitely maps to `!`" and `.` means "might map to either `!` or   depending on the accumulator value."

We want to run our loop from 3 to 16 in this function; since loop variables in *Acc!!* always start at zero, we'll just add 3 to the loop variable `c`.

Next, we combine the pairs of characters that will always be the same by int-dividing by 2:

```
0123456789
!!.....!!.
```

We can get the periodic behavior if we take this input mod 7:

```
0123456
!!.....
```

Now it's just a matter of adjusting the cutoff depending on the input value. Conceptually, we want exclamation points if this number is less than `L+2`, and spaces if it is greater than or equal to `L+2`. Conveniently, `L+2` is the value in the accumulator. Inconveniently, *Acc!!* doesn't have comparison operators, so we'll have to abuse some arithmetic:

With integer division, and assuming `b` is always positive, `a/b` is `0` if `a<b` and some positive number otherwise. To turn 0 vs positive into 1 vs 0, we can add 1 (making it 1 vs greater than 1) and then int-divide 1 by that quantity. End result: `1/(a/b+1)` is `1` if `a<b` and `0` otherwise.

In our case, we have `a = (c+3)/2%7` and `b = _` (the accumulator). Substituting those into the above expression and adding to `32` gives exclamation point (ASCII 33) or space (ASCII 32) exactly where we want them.

```
}
Write 10
}
```

Close the `c` loop, write a newline, and close the `l` loop.

```
Count h while h-12 {
Write 33
}
Write 10
```

Output the top/bottom of the battery: Loop 12 times and write exclamation point; then write a newline.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 82 bytes

```
n->[print(l)|l<-[s="############",e=Strchr([35-3*(j>n+n&j<11)|j<-[0..13]]),e,e,s]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifZvs/T9cuuqAoM69EI0ezJsdGN7rYVkkZCSjppNoGlxQlZxRpRBub6hpraWTZ5WnnqWXZGBpq1mQBNRjo6Rkax8Zq6qQCYXFs7P80DQNNrjQNQxBhBCKMQYQJiDDV/A8A)

This code is most probably not the shortest possible, as this is my first time golfing in Pari/GP.

Thanks @alephalpha for -14 bytes.

Comment: You can use list comprehension instead of a for loop. [87 bytes.](https://tio.run/##TcsxCoQwEIXhfk8hI8gMJmLW3c54kZBCxEiCjEEtvXs0ne@Hr3tx3L1cYnI6sRxM3D2fuNK19tIcGsrXQMx62ngaTzTeYRi45ir0SgkoQEAJdIXn1TaN6qwlMT8d1iaHLX0cqsw302V@mT@lGw "Pari/GP – Try It Online")

Comment: Even shorter using `Strchr` to convert integers to strings: [82 bytes.](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifZvs/T9cuuqAoM69EI0ezJsdGN7rYVkkZCSjppNoGlxQlZxRpRBub6hpraWTZ5WnnqWXZGBpq1mQBNRjo6Rkax8Zq6qQCYXFs7P80DQNNrjQNQxBhBCKMQYQJiDDV/A8A "Pari/GP – Try It Online")

Comment: @alephalpha Thanks for the tips! I'm sure I'll be using these in the future. I wanted to ask, is there a way to do string multiplication in Pari/GP? Like `"#"*12` in python.

Comment: There is no string multiplication. The shortest way I can think of is `concat(["#"|i<-[1..12]])`, but that is already longer than `"############"`.

Comment: -2 bytes by using exclamation marks instead: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifZvs/T9cuuqAoM69EI0ezJsdGN7rYVkkRCSjppNoGlxQlZxRpRBsb62pk2eVp56ll2RgaatZkAZUb6OkZGsfGauqkAmFxbOz/NA0DTa40DUMQYQQijEGECYgw1fwPAA "Pari/GP – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 18 bytes

```
d×*₀↲×p14e:"×12*p∞
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJkw5cq4oKA4oayw5dwMTRlOlwiw5cxMipw4oieIiwi4oGLIiwiMyJd)

```
d                  # Input * 2
 ×*                # That many asterisks
   ₀↲              # Pad the left to length 10 with spaces
     ×p            # Prepend an asterisk
       14e         # Extend to length 14 by appending the first char
          :"       # Pair with itself
                p  # Prepend to this...
            ×12*   # 12 asterisks
                 ∞ # Palindromise the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 55 bytes

```
.+
#$&$*_10$* ###¶
+`(_*)_  
##$1
.+¶
12$*#¶$&$&$&12$*#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLWUVNRSve0EBFS0FZWfnQNi7tBI14Lc14BQUuZWUVQy49baCYoZGKFlAOqBQIwZz//40A) Explanation:

```
.+
#$&$*_10$* ###¶
```

Produce a body row of the empty battery but include `L` `_`s.

```
+`(_*)_  
##$1
```

For each `_`, delete two spaces and add two `#`s.

```
.+¶
12$*#¶$&$&$&12$*#
```

Triplicate the row and wrap it in lines of 12 `#`s.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) with `-lm`, <s>93</s> 91 bytes

- -2 thanks to ceilingcat

Uses `9` as the fill character. I make use of 10<sup>*n*</sup>-1 producing *n* nines when *n*>0.

```c
*s="999999999999";f(i,j){for(puts(s),j=3;j--;printf("%-11.f999\n",exp10(i-~i)-1));puts(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU3LCsIwELznK0JAyNquNAiCrP0TLyWasqGP0FQRSv10YwoenMMwDPOw2Fqb0j7W6vwHRU5z6WFx46TDY446QunrI3lEChMPs9Nqh8YcXE5fB1XeX8FUmvHNgAaAfiVaUw7LvuFBP0e@gVyElJvFJLLa9rmuSPLllKkoQOZnILGmj3Vd08aEXf8F)

Comment: you can get down to 90 if you use hex instead of decimal (I expected more but oh well): `*s="ffffffffffff";f(i,j){for(puts(s),j=3;j--;printf("%-11lxfff\n",(16l<<i*8)-1));puts(s);}`

Comment: or down to 88 if you use strings (and it lets you use any output character): `short*s="############";f(i,j){for(puts(s),j=3;j--;printf("#%-10s###\n",s+6-i));puts(s);}`

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.8, <s>85</s> <s>72</s> <s>68</s> <s>49</s> 46 bytes

```py
lambda l,a="##":[a*6,*3*[f'#{l*a:10}###'],a*6]
```

Outputs a list of strings, as allowed by [standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcnBCkBAEADQX9nMwe40B1LSli/BYcSi1tg2F8m3L7m9euE610OqJsTk2j553seJlSduM4DMdow1YYWdy@H2yLYsHgDIB/piSO6IStQmKrIss66NxZ2DDnGTk5wWY@i3NukF)

-13 thx to @Aiden chow

-4 thx to @ovs

-3 thx to @Aiden chow

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9FWSVmJq6AoM69EQykmT0kvKz8zTyM6UcvQSCfZyjZNqTpRGySXmVdQWqKhqallpJVoZWhYq6ysrKSTDIQglbGamv//GwMA) by converting c into an f-string and some other optimizations.

Comment: [Additional -4](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9FWSVmJq6AoM69EI1HL0Egn2co2Tak6URskkJlXUFqioampZaSVaGVoWKusrKykkwyEYJXFqQW26jF56pr//xsDAA) by using the `sep` argument of `print`.

Comment: is this looking too much like pxeger's answer?

Comment: @DialFrost yeah it's looking really similar to pxeger's answer, though it's still a little different so i think it's fine.

Comment: Also [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcnBCkBAEADQX9nMwe40B1LSli/BYcSi1tg2F8m3L7m9euE610OqJsTk2j553seJlSduM4DMdow1YYWdy@H2yLYsHgDIB/piSO6IStQmKrIss66NxZ2DDnGTk5wWY@i3NukF) (different from pxeger's answer)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>57 51</s> 48 bytes

```julia
c='#';!n=[c^12,(h=rpad(c*c^2n,11)*c^3;),h,h,c^12]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoAgEADAr5QFapmwRZdEPxIKYgeLRSIKOvR3K@Y624WrhzvnoGlFVZn0HBz0gkV97H5hwTFo@8QFAG@CGxQX8fMfm2EaC/kY7Mx@rOnEJNlMUNdIVImKEMvzCw)

-3 MarcMush

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P9lWXVndWjHPNjo5ztBIRyPDtqggMUUjWSs5zihPx9BQMznO2FpTJwMIQQpi/xtamSro1djl6NoVFGXmleTk6WlEK@XYquQoWSvmWCspxWr@BwA "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>82</s> 74 bytes

<sup>It [Taylor Rained](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243337/draw-a-battery-indicator/243408?noredirect=1#comment547967_243408) 8 bytes.</sup>

```
=LET(a,REPT("#",12),b,MID(a&REPT(" ",10),12-2*A1,11)&"###
",a&"
"&b&b&b&a)
```

Input of `L` is in the cell `A1`. Output is wherever the formula is. For best results, make sure the column is wide enough, text wrapping is on, and the font is monospace. The output will be correct regardless but this makes that fact visually apparent.

- `LET(a,REPT("#",12)` defines `a` to be 12 number signs in a row. Combining `LET()` and `REPT()` only saves us 1-3 bytes but savings are savings.
- `b,MID(a&REPT(" ",10),12-2*A1,11)&"###\n"` has a lot going one but the summary is this:

  - Create a string of 12 `#` and 10 spaces.
  - Find the right spot (based on the input) in the middle of that string to start pulling characters.
  - Pull 11 characters (1 `#` + 2*input `#` + however many spaces).
  - Add `###` and a line break.
  - Set the resulting string to the variable `b`.
- `a&"\n"&b&b&b&a` concatenates the pieces into an output.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: you can get to 74 bytes with `=LET(a,REPT("#",12),b,MID(a&REPT(" ",10),12-2*A1,11)&"###\n",a&"\n"&b&b&b&a)` or `=LET(a,REPT("#",12),a&"\n"&REPT(MID(a&REPT(" ",10),12-2*A1,11)&"###\n",3)&a)`

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 202 bytes

```
+++++[>++>++++++<<-]>>++>-............<<.>>>>++++[->+++<]>>>>>+++++++[<+++++++>-],<--[>-<-]>[<+<+<+>>>-]<<<[<[-<+<+>>]<[>+<-]>>[<<++<-->>>-]<<-[-<<.>>]<[-<<.>>]<...<<.>>>>>>>[[<+>-]>]<<[<]>>]<[<<<.>>>-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU27CsNADPugq7J0FfoR4yEJBEqhQ6Hff5Uvj1YeTtbJ0vKeH6/tsz57b4VQaxqskUjViukP5CRpWAL1MHUKpfEgQt4IhFAxlmvsQ5IMBvY96cZRFPSpLw4P7Kiq5EV@7UY40kbLTsvh4/6L7P3@BQ)

first, I try to comment this shorter bytes brainfuck to first brainfuck(245 bytes) comment, but i don't have enough reputation. so i decide to comment here and give the link to [that first comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243350/111206).
also if I can, I will try to expaining this code later

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <strike><sup>76</sup></strike> 70 bytes

-6 thanks to Hannesh

```js
_=>(a=`############
`)+`#${'##'.repeat(_).padEnd(10)}###
`.repeat(3)+a
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbe1k4j0TZBGQlwJWhqJyirVKsrK6vrFaUWpCaWaMRr6hUkprjmpWgYGmjWghXBpIw1tRP/p@UXaWTaGlhn2phZZ2pra1ZzKSgk5@cV5@ek6uXkp2ukaWRqanLV/gcA)

Comment: Could save 6 bytes by using `.padEnd(10)` instead of `+'  '.repeat(5-_)`

Answer (score 2):

## C++, 267 bytes

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#define c std::cin
#define o std::cout
#define h()o<<H<<'\n'
#define L 12
#define H 111111111111
#define M 1
typedef int I;
I main(){I l;c>>l;h();for(I i=0;i<3;i++){o<<M;for(I j=0;j<l*2;j++){o<<1;}for(I k=0;k<L-l*2-2;k++){o<<' ';}o<<111<<'\n';}h();}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##TY7LCoMwEEX3fsWAC7UiNHbnpK4r6B90IzG24yORNl0U8dttRAmd3T1nmDtimpKHEOvqkxLDp5Gc9Nu8ZD3mnt/IlpQEAW/TZJkg5ZA@kP4Yx55hpDm/cR7cVeBoCSx14QbsbxyugHnmO0kbgZSBAgsYa1JhNBcwoMjzAe11bPUrLICuZyR@QYrjaLaN1cE7yzs@nFLsDsNw2VVvVc/LxMokxf7QAQS4bGuM7U/jsrUs68p@)

First time golfing in C++, not sure if it's good or not.

Comment: [162 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYtBCoMwEADvviJECqbNQgM9mehLepEY68qaFY2n0renLUI7x2HGLws8vM@5xOhp74ND3tIaurktyj4MGINgsaW@rj3vyTnz06Ng56T5c4/SFhiTII3NTU927jBW6nncGNuW7MBrNQKgXdZPOVTydN6OVZsrEJCWUqlvNTV0Ic12ArCK7fjK2bwB "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 86 bytes

```python
a,b="#"*12,int(input())
c="#"+"#"*2*b+" "*(10-2*b)+"###"
print("\n".join([a,c,c,c,a]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1EnyVZJWUnL0EgnM69EIzOvoLREQ1OTKxkkqg2SMdJK0lZSUNLSMDTQBbI1gYLKykpcBUUg9UoxeUp6WfmZeRrRiTrJYJgYq6n5/78RAA)

Quick and dirty, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 49 bytes

```
Ｐ×-¹²Ｐ↓×-⁵≔Ｎα↓→Ｆ³«Ｐ×-×α²↓»Ｐ×-¹¹Ｆχ«→»Ｐ↑×-⁴Ｆ³«↑Ｐ×-³`
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@3NKckM6AoM69EIyQzN7VYQ0lXSUfB0EhTkwtJysolvzxPRwFJhSlQgWNxcWZ6noZnXkFpiV9pblJqkYamjkIiUGd@WSpED4wdlJmeUaLJ5ZZfpKBhrFnNxYndXggzUUcBaL8mUBGSObVcOJxqqAk2V8PQQFOhGqYHah@KJqvQAhQvmEA1QtwD1hZaoInLacZA1bX//5v81y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code.

My second Charcoal answer!

Uses "`-`" instead of "`#`" because if I change, The Output uses both "-" and "#".

### Explanation:

TODO: Understand the code and explain

Comment: Trivial golfs: `↓→` can be `↘`; `Ｆχ«→»` can be `Ｆχ→` or `Ｍχ→`; `Ｐ×-¹²` can be `Ｐ¹²` (but not when using `↓`); `≔Ｎα` can be `Ｎα` (but I normally use `θ` instead of `α`).

Comment: @Neil Thanks for 8 bytes.

Comment: Actually the `Ｐ×-` was just an example; you can do the same simplification to `Ｐ` in a couple of other places too.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <strike>98,</strike> 95 bytes

```java
L->{System.out.format("%s"+"%2$-11s###\n".repeat(3)+"%1$s","############\n","#".repeat(L-~L));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9BS8QwEIXv@yuGdBcSaoN18RTrxZNQT3tUDzGbLqltUpLJgpT61@soi@zAMPC@x@NNr8@66o@fqxl0SvCinYd5AzDlj8EZSKiRzjm4I4zE@AGj86fXd9DxlARZewqQGd0gu@wNuuDls8en4FMebYQOmrWtHufDV0I7ypBRdiGOGjnbJVay3d22qutUFMWbZzLayRLaCwL1NrEbVlwNOUj4d7XVdyuEWlZFfQEoFrjzCA4auFV0Hpp75cpSzH@cHFIbYyfkTqiLdFVrosdw8PzCls3vLusP)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>19</s> 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
X12×$·×Tj7bìĆRD».∊
```

Outputs `1` instead of `#`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9vc2FiaWX//1gxMsOXJMK3w5dUajdiw6zEhlJEwrsu4oiK//8y) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W96bJKSZ15BaYmVgpK9nw6Xkn9pCYSn8z/C0OjwdEO/Q9sPTw/JMk86vOZIW5DLod16jzq6/usc2mb/HwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
X               # Push 1
 12             # Push 12
   ×            # Repeat the "1" 12 times: 111111111111
$               # Push 1 and the input
 ·              # Double the input
  ×             # Repeat the "1" that many times
   Tj           # Pad it with leading spaces up to length 10
     7bì        # Prepend the binary of 7: 111
        Ć       # Enclose; append its own head
         R      # Reverse it
          D     # Duplicate it
           »    # Join the stack with newline delimiter
            .∊  # Mirror it vertically with overlap
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Noether](https://github.com/beta-decay/Noether), 76 bytes

```
I~l12("#"P!i)?3(0~rl2*1+("#"P!r)0~r11l2*-(r0{>}{" "P}!r)"###"P?!k)12("#"P!y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8tPLclILfr/37Mux9BIQ0lZKUAxU9PeWMOgrijHSMtQGyJUpAnkGxoCRXQ1igyq7WqrlRSUAmqB4krKykAF9orZmjDtlZr//xsBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 63 bytes

```perl
$_=($s='#'x12 .$/).('#'.'#'x($x=2*$_).$"x(10-$x)."###\n")x3 .$s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoAgEEDR/ZwidEANmlJz6U2CVi2CMMkWc/qmWv7Hr9t1JBFcs8WWjTbsQ0c4OrJf0A8WOYceV0eo2PppQHaktNZLUY7jdzeRCTwEiDBDes5672dpMtTjBQ)

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##Dcg7CsAgDADQPacQE1AH06@jNyk4dSiIldrB0zd1e7x6PjmIUIqWWjRo@rI6pontMBscQYm1Urrb4Ck51oh4FO36ppiayAwLrLDBDuG763vdpYmv@Qc "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Nice, no need for $x here.

Comment: Nice, I came up with pretty much the same approach for [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcgxDoAgDADAva8gTQcYRAsyGX5CwuRgQoSoQ19v9cYb@9WSUsk0b0o1Wyo@s3Bw3iIwemah6tEYFJsmqu4fdhJVF2AIEGGF9PbxHP28dRrtAw "Perl 5 – Try It Online"), but it does necessitate resetting ``$\`` in your test suite (works as a single run without a problem though!)

Comment: Gosh, nice too. I missed the fine print about allowing other chars than `#`.

Answer (score 1):

## J, <s>50</s> <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```
(a,3 1#(a=:12#'#'),:~'# #'#~(>:,10&-,3:)@+:)
```

Found that building row by row can be shorter.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NRJ1jBUMlTUSba0MjZTVldU1dazq1JUVgMw6DTsrHUMDNV0dYytNB20rzf@aXFypyRn5CmkKhhCGujpMwPg/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 87 bytes

```lua
x,b=...,"\n"d=b.rep a=d("#",12)print(a..b..d(b.format("%-11s###\n",d("#",1+2*x)),3)..a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704pzRxwYKlpSVpuhY3wyt0kmz19PR0lGLylFJsk_SKUgsUEm1TNJSUlXQMjTQLijLzSjQS9fSS9PRSNJL00vKLchNLNJRUdQ0Ni5WVlYG6dKCKtY20KjQ1dYw19fQSNSHGQ21ZHG0UC2UCAA)

[image]

My alternate approach before the format string was 6 bytes longer at **93 bytes**:

```lua
x,b=...,"\n"d,f=b.rep,''a=d("#",12)print(a..b..d(d("#",1+2*x)..d(" ",10-2*x).."###"..b,3)..a)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 29 bytes

```
i:00YPiX6L3P[iJiXa.sXt-2*ai]y
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZ7M60MDCIDMiPMfIwDojO9MiMS9YojSnSNtBIzYyshaqBKF0cbxUKZAA)

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 51 bytes

Prompts for n

```
t←14↑12⍴'#'⋄v←3 14⍴' '⋄v[;(⍳1+2×⎕),11+⍳3]←'#'⋄t⍪v⍪t
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tfwmIafKobaKh0aPeLerK6o@6W8pAChWAokABBbBAtLXGo97NhtpGh6cD9WvqGBpqA/nGsUCFEC0lj3pXlQFxyX@gqVz/07gMuIBaudK4DKG0EZQ2htImUNqUCwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 45 bytes

```powershell
%{'#'*12;"#{0,-10}###`n"-f('##'*$_)*3+'#'*12}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyflvoKdnWvNftVpdWV3L0MhaSbnaQEfX0KBWWVk5IU9JN01DXRkooxKvqWWsDVFT@/8/AA)

Try it in a PS console (Windows or Core):

```powershell
 0..5|%{'#'*12;"#{0,-10}###`n"-f('##'*$_)*3+'#'*12}
```

### Explanation

`%` is an Alias for the Cmdlet "ForEach-Object", which accepts input from the pipeline and processes each incoming object inside the ScriptBlock `{...}`
`'#'*12;` First line, PowerShell can "multiply" strings; the `;` terminates the command, output is implicit.
`` "#{0,-10}###`n" `` The level row; `{0,-10}` is a placeholder where the first argument of the following `-f` format operator will be inserted. `-10` will print the string inserted left-aligned, and padded to a length of 10. The  `` `n `` is a newline.
`-f('##'*$_)` Inserts the actual level into the row using the `-f` format operator; `$_` is the current input value.
`*3` Multiplies the level row created by `` "#{0,-10}###`n"-f('##'*$_) `` three times
`+'#'*12` Adds the last line to the level rows created above.
Output is implicit.

Comment: The code `%{...}` is a code sinppet, not a program or function.

Comment: We had that discussion before at [Return all letter counts as an integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238533/return-all-letter-counts-as-an-integer/238570#238570), and I stand by what I said there. `ForEach-Object` (aka `%`) is a built-in function/cmdlet which takes input from stdin, which is a perfectly allowed method. What exactly is your issue with that?

Comment: 1. I remember. I have written for other readers. 2. You are not using a `stdin` in your code, you are using a piece of [pipe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) - code snippet. 3. please use TIO field `input` if you want use `stdin`. Thanks.

Comment: This is most definitely not a snippet, this is **a fully functional PowerShell command**. You can paste the code as shown into a PS shell, and it will run as it is. And using stdin as input means input through the pipeline, ever since the concept of input and output streams was invented; you're splitting hairs here, and I have no idea why.

Comment: The `pipeline` is not `stdin`. The `pipeline` is a PowerShell expression and should be included in the counted code.

Comment: Are you talking about the pipe symbol `|`? That causes the invocation of the code, and passing the argument(s) through stdin. Since when does the invocation count against the code that's executed?

Comment: The result of the "passing the argument(s) through stdin" is the string `0..5`. You are using a powershell pipe, so the header from your TIO should be included in the section being counted. Again: the code `%{...}` is a code sinppet, not a program or function. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Again: the code `%{...}` is a fully functional PowerShell command. You can paste it as it is into a PS console (it's a Shell as well as script engine, after all), and you'll get the results for an empty battery. Piping the test cases 0 to 5 to this code is allowed by [Programs may take input via STDIN](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2448/78395), so that can't possibly be counted against the code. I think that makes a pretty solid case, while you, so far, haven't posted a single argument why this should be considered a snippet, you just keep repeating that it is.

Comment: "Again: the code %{...} is a fully functional PowerShell command." I'm agree - it is a PS command. I wrote: "The code %{...} is a code sinppet, not a program or function". STDIN and Powershell pipline is not same things. You don't understand the difference. My English is not good enough to explain to you. Your  Header code should be in the counting TIO section. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
２×╵#×α⁵∔ ×#３×）∑３＊#⁶×ｑ；Ｏ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjEyJUQ3JXUyNTc1JTIzJUQ3JXUwM0IxJXUyMDc1JXUyMjE0JTIwJUQ3JTIzJXVGRjEzJUQ3JXVGRjA5JXUyMjExJXVGRjEzJXVGRjBBJTIzJXUyMDc2JUQ3JXVGRjUxJXVGRjFCJXVGRjJG,i=Mw__,v=8)

#### Explanation:

```
２×╵                         push input*2+1 (called n)
    #×                       repeat '#' n times
      α⁵∔ ×                  repeat ' ' 11-n times
           #３×               repeat '#' 3 times
               ）∑            join
                  ３＊         repeat 3 times vertically
                     #⁶×       repeat '#' 12 times
                        ｑ；Ｏ  print without popping, reverse stack, print stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 38 bytes

```
li2*:I;'#:OC*N+_O_I*+AI-S*+O3*+N+3*\++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/PyfTSMvK01pd2crfWctPO94/3lNL29FTN1hL299YS9tP21grRlv7/38jAA)