# Repeat Hello World according to another string's length

Tags: code-golf, string, hello-world

This was related to a program I am writing. Although the title is simple, the challenge is a lot more complicated.

### Your challenge

You must write a program that takes an input, and your answer must match the sample outputs in this question.

What the program should be is that you must output "HelloWorld" with the length of the input matching the length of what you output. If the input's length is not divisible with 10, you should cut off the last few letters until it matches the length of the last few letters of the input. More clarification in the examples.

**Standard loopholes apply, except that answers should be full programs, and the input has to be printable ASCII.**

### Example inputs

```
Input:  how are you
Output: HelloWorldH 

Note: In the above example, there is an extra H due to the 
characters in the input being 11, so we add an extra letter

Input:  hrienehwnv
Output: HelloWorld

Input:  kill him at dawn
Output: HelloWorldHelloW
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins!

---

Steffan won the first +50 bounty reputation award for 5 bytes. I know lyxal also had a 5 bytes with the same language, but previously he had his answer with 8 bytes, before he shortened it to 5 bytes, but after Steffan's answer had already been posted.

Comment: BTW, the answers seem to be assuming [Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447) , writing functions or lambdas that take 2 operands.  Not whole *programs*, because in many languages that requires a lot of uninteresting boilerplate.  Your phrasing requires a program. You could avoid that by rephrasing to "you must take 2 inputs ... and output a string with the same length, filled with repeats of the string HelloWorld".  Then answers can write programs or functions, whatever they like.

Comment: I'd like to understand what exactly the second input is supposed to mean in your suggested edit "you must take **2** inputs ... and output a string with the same length, filled with repeats of the string HelloWorld"

Comment: Brain fart, I was probably thinking of the general case of filling a buffer of a given length with repeats of a shorter string (or a substring of a longer string).  That's what this is, where the input string is really just an integer length (or also a buffer for you to overwrite in-place), and the string you're filling with is a fixed input.

Comment: What that challenge meant was that: the user gives in a string input to the program. The program outputs "HelloWorld" repeatedly, and strips off extra letters, to match the length of the user input. It has no connection with buffers.

Comment: "Filling a buffer" is just the terminology I'm using to describe the the interesting core part of the problem in terms of a C or assembly implementation, separate from actual I/O.  i.e. generating a string in memory.  Of course an implementation in a higher-level language wouldn't be in those terms, just manipulation of string variables (but still often not IO). If you did want to disallow functions and require answers to be whole programs, you should edit to explicitly say you're overriding [Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to only contain letters (both lower- and uppercase) and spaces?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen the contents of the input doesn't matter; the length of the input is what the program modifies the output based on.

Comment: I assume Kevin is considering an implementation in some language using a search/replace function or something like that, in which case the contents could matter.  Remember, this is code-golf, where any guarantee might potentially be useful for a hacky implementation, even if that would be irrelevant for a sane clean implementation.

Comment: *"[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)"*

Comment: In that case, if you want to know, it should contain printable ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
LkhȧẎ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJMa2jIp+G6jiIsIiIsImhvdyBhcmUgeW91Il0=)

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript, <del>45</del> 35 bytes

```javascript
s=>"".padEnd(s.length,"HelloWorld")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADAr5hOkCizC24m/sCZSAFNQwk06O/x7nHdtaveRZa@jmBHsxuAKc7v2atmCHOUNMOBRHxyJQ96XJwbExriqIKCNznBjnUS/AS0Hj8)

−10 thanks to Arnauld.

Comment: `padEnd()` is probably the best option here ([35 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr4QXFcof2C3oB51FVy0WV3Sxfm8zjxuu@3ZX3goFmNHObncpTXXhKEF1g1AS51WcgEgXNQxCT0@lE4JBSioq8WbHMKAtDB8LrecP))

Answer (score 8):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>111</s> <s>55</s> <s>51</s> 44 bytes

```
s/./a/
:a
s/^/HelloWorld/
s/.\{10\}$//
/a/ba
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlwYKlpSVpuhY3dYr19fQT9bmsErmK9eP0PVJzcvLD84tyUvSBfL2YakODmFoVfX0uoJqkRIgeqNYFN9Uz8ssVEotSFSrzS7kyijJT81IzyvPKuLIzc3IUMjJzFRJLFFISy_Mg6gE)

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
map fst.zip(cycle"HelloWorld")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPzexQCGtuESvKrNAI7kyOSdVyQMolR@eX5SToqQJlM7MU7BVAKryVdAoKC0JLinyydNL01RQUYhWysgvV0gsSlWozC9V0lFQyijKTM1LzSjPKwPxEMZAWEqx//8lp@Ukphf/100uKAAA)

A cute way to truncate one string to the length of another is to `zip` them together, which truncates the longer string, then extract the desired string with `map fst`.

Longer alternatives:

```hs
fst.unzip.zip(cycle"HelloWorld")
zipWith const$cycle"HelloWorld"
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 39 bytes

```python
lambda s:('HelloWorld'*len(s))[:len(s)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYwxCgIxEEV7TzHdZEV7CdjrCSzWLSJJSHB2siRZw57FJiB6J28jS6zef_B5z8-0ZBe4vuzx-p6z3R--SGq8aQVJCjwZonAJkTRuybBIXdfLNob__WxDhASeoUcXCqhoYAkz7gBd9IaNK_xY7e6JwPkRVAatCuMgNwBT9JyFXcstWGvjDw)

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 39 bytes

Alternative version proposed by `mazunki`:

```python
lambda s:('HelloWorld'*(l:=len(s)))[:l]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxBCsIwEADvvmJvm4reJdC7vsBD20MkCQluNyVJDX2Ll4Don_yNlHoaBoZ5fqYlu8D1Zdv-PWd7PH2R1HjTCpIUeDZE4RoiadwLki0ZFqlpmk7S8M8vNkRI4Bk6dKGAigaWMOMB0EVv2LjCj9XungicH0Fl0KowDnIHMEXPWdj1ug1r3fgD)

Comment: If we could somehow `l=len(s)` there, that'd maybe strip some bytes?

`lambda s:("helloworld"*(l:=len(s)))[:l]` has the same lenght, not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: The other way would be Python, 41 bytes: [`lambda s,l=len:('HelloWorld'*l(s))[:l(s)]`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYwxDsIgFEB3T_E3wNTdkHTXEzjUDhggEH8_DVBJz-JCYvRO3saQOr284b3nZ16zC1Rftr--l2wPx69ANd20gtRhj4YkZyeDGC4homZ75EmIQTaM_-BsQ4QEnmBgLhRQ0cAaFtYBc9EbMq7Qo9ndI4LzE6gMWhVio9wBzNFT5rZ9t2GtG38) but it's longer.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
…HelloWorldＬＳ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMO5Mjkn1Tkjv0BDySM1Jyc/PL8oJ0VJR8EnNS@9JEPDM6@gtCS4BKg0XUMTCKz//8/IL1dILEpVqMwv5fqvW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 HelloWorld     Literal string `HelloWorld`
…               Reshaped to length
           Ｌ    Length of
            Ｓ   Input string
```

Comment: Best answer - no dictionary lookup tomfoolery!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
”Ÿ™‚ï”áI∍
```

Input as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPcozsetSx61DDr8Hog5/BCz0cdvf//RytlKOko5QNxORArAHEiEBcBcSqUXwmVL1WKBQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVw6P9HDXOP7njUsuhRw6zD64GcwwsjHnX0/tf5H62UkV@ukFiUqlCZX6qko6CUUZSZmpeaUZ5XBuJlZ@bkKGRk5iokliikJJbngcQMjYxNlGIB).

**Explanation:**

```python
”Ÿ™‚ï”     # Push dictionary string "Hello World"
      á    # Only keep letters to remove the space: "HelloWorld"
       I   # Push the input-list
        ∍  # Shorten/extend the "HelloWorld" string to its length
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `”Ÿ™‚ï”` is `"Hello World"`.

Comment: This is larger than 9 bytes with any Unicode encoding. More like 16.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe 05AB1E uses, just like some other golfing languages you'll see on CGCC like Jelly, Charcoal, Vyxal, etc. [its own codepage](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) for the 256 characters it knows. Each of these characters are 1 byte each in this encoding. I'm not sure how to run the new 05AB1E version (which compiles with Elixir) in Bash, but [here is an example of running the raw bytes in this encoding](https://tinyurl.com/2m29w2hp) for the legacy version of 05AB1E, which compiles in Python.

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, 38 bytes

```
=LEFT(REPT("HelloWorld",3276),LEN(A1))
```

Input is in the cell `A1`. Output is wherever the formula is.

Repeats the string as many times as allowed based on the limitations of inputs to `LEFT()` and the truncates all but the left-most characters based on the length of the input.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 55 bytes

```c
main(c){for(;~getchar();)printf(L"dHelloWorl"+c++%10);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoQgEADQX5EgUCSo2y7SvUP3zsOYJk0aKnSI9tN3eg87j8h8QIgS1e1Slubn14obZKmMOnOI1cm5sdNKlJaUqdGodTv0yjzMeyASWzgEVGHhin90BL5wV6od8fN9AQ)

Comment: Is this a function or a full program?

Comment: @py3programmer [here](https://tio.run/##JcixCsIwEADQ3a8ILULSWtE54uwfdBCH45Imh9dE0rQOop9upLg9HnbIEFwpNQXk2djTlA3FvT9vKGQxAgW5AnfoITXNol5DTFJ/nM3rSKXVY/6zMhfLHPuYuLpi226Ph5vS71LuxCw8jQKyMPAMXxwY3FS6Hph/) is a C11 compliant and cross platform (the [printf trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250732/112488) only works on a little-endian architecture) implementation of the same program for clarity

Comment: It is a full program. It can be compiled with `cc <program_name>` using any c89 compiler on a little endian machine, if you intend to run it I recommend running it as `printf '%s' '<test_input>' | ./a.out`, to avoid confusion with `'\n'` in the input

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 25 bytes

```
FNrZlwp@"HelloWorld"%N 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/382vKCqnvMBBySM1Jyc/PL8oJ0VJ1U/B0OD//4z8coXEolSFyvxSAA)

PS: first time using Pyth & this platform is awesome!

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 27 bytes

```
T`p`~
Y`~`\He\l\l\oW\or\l\d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/PyShIKGOKzKhLiHGIzUmBwjzw2Pyi4B0yv//GfnlColFqQqV@aUA) Explanation:

```
T`p`~
```

Translate all the characters to `~`s.

```
Y`~`\He\l\l\oW\or\l\d
```

Cyclically translate all the `~`s to the characters `HelloWorld`. Note that unfortunately most of them have special meanings to translate so that they have to be quoted.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pl`, 23 bytes

Inspiration taken from [@Neil's Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250518/9365). 3 bytes saved thanks to [@Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus)!

```perl
$_&=HelloWorld x y//./c
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiMDAwMDAwMDA6IDI0NWYgMjYzZCA0ODY1IDZjNmMgNmY1NyA2ZjcyIDZjNjQgMjA3OCAgJF8mPUhlbGxvV29ybGQgeFxuMDAwMDAwMTA6IDIwNzkgMmYyZiBmZjJmIDYzICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHkvLy4vYyIsImFyZ3MiOiItcGwiLCJpbnB1dCI6ImFcbmFCQ1xuQWJDRGVmZ0hJamtsbW5PUHFyU3RVdiJ9)

### Explanation

Sets `$_` (which will be implicitly output via `-p`) to the result of stringwise `AND`ing a string of `HelloWorld`s repeated once for the count of each char in the input (implicitly stored in `$_` via the implicit `-n` from `-p`) when `tr///`ansliterated (`y///`) from any char to `\xFF`s. This operation results in a string the length of the original input with the content `HelloWorld` truncated accordingly.

Comment: You should be able to use the return value of `s` by doing `HelloWorld x s/./\x7f/g`. Save an additional byte by using `y//\x7f/c` instead

Comment: @Sisyphus thanks! I didn't think to use the replacement in that position, but since it still executes before the rest, that makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 5 bytes

```
ẏkhȧİ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwi4bqPa2jIp8SwIiwiIiwiR2FtaW4iXQ==)

Can't believe I had to find a new 5 byter because someone got my answer by 2 bytes shorter :p.

### Explained

```
ẏkhȧİ
ẏ     # The range [0, len(input)]
 khȧ  # The string "HelloWorld"
    İ # The range indexed into the characters of the string.
```

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `sr`, 5 bytes

```
khȧf•
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzcmEiLCIiLCJraMinZuKAoiIsIiIsImJcbnJcbnVcbmhcbm1cbm9cbm1cbmVcbm5cbnRcbi4iXQ==)

More flags and more ways that I won't be outgolfed again. Takes input as a list of characters

#### Explained

```
khȧf•
khȧf  # The string "HelloWorld" as a list of chars
    • # Molded to the shape of the input
```

Comment: Steffan has a 2 bytes lesser answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 23 bytes

```
O G*"HelloWorld"=cL P0c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLCeyYKu2bGSKZIGjjkAWks0H8AUhy1h1suyTZFiOcH89293zopFtspe75YNlzTzd0/1MT3ePibp3UfTtVZJF6XIc7xXlOJm/ng6b5kia3NaGovJxEa@A8iS7qw2VyUxgxvEkyWKWpiydZ3f00dSjH88@vWe96vXy4wXzq9ffDi7YbvV6dPaO/Vy9XnxivQp8dHppYM8@nRrQT2fvDy7/bhec2fjRZv/p/cT17MElLCsmo2mYM4dXAiYKbNUqhkO2W82dHX7GyQwmyaOvDL/v7a1gcBnCoJuASVOOwBrm7fn5KYHwY5@c7KNvhiEXxwIA8oat92G6jDm/yka82SQ/YFeuRsFF6/D8yP52zo6d1t/iNJ1/nufpuBVEp@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@3GDjCAcxifcxeaKYKMkp8wlUb7UZTQzjJkb3ruT2ODuKwdoIczJZpGuaPpqPV/lwY2/PB0pbRglJ@ma1I0xI9XEImhU2eHhy@fXfz69bpL@eGw6ba22SjXn9d71ZN8fHJ5QsayzgnlWE2Zv9ahuoV1d6bS@ysLyEIOLY0FycbuCDh3bpwHfNMqTJfZrhDA5l9nXJe2CpX0gGA0C6TiNHs7XJy5e@OpB1io9uUHrQBxQKOVTmxAQr@b6eQtFXeoerjopJVBXAotAJR18T6Ndwe6@3U/UTnMRb3WavMl3ELYlCPY0jC@CSEDIITLYysVkUC@om@ywJEdHx5O5@nMHNbZ@BFXyu3vueQ8@MemWberpmZoo3ZX2ojBG05T1PbNNVlngsV4n8wOVszGavw@4MPZy7WYhFo8Hpy1fM8D8IJXIFX9VYk/46/lAwfAyNGDW@RAXhz8cOnz52gp0o6Zjis6vigT188dgBwdHJ66LAJJMdBQ4e2XA/TcBQu3DTOqAMwuFL9keAMzt1LZKwKYm3C0oYFx06ol4BavEdcDKCoJDip80Y0W6zsAJGUjKoUgjQlI1ymeEjKaGo7wMxaOwUcMfkXYZ2yDqw@w1UEIEBCsSGDLMzb5JRUL1vCWsjyAVXhCkF9Z5lj6aLW82rEn6owgwaKcrtY@AIWruvOIePZvO39PsG/CvkBkKBVcHQXlyl0jXab9rKNO4QlcpxkfJBMbJv2ExuCaJqjLS7EKedimwNvsNFWeHBqA8R6h2I90TliNpCEDJS9SJLMnZWVbyt/BF7PvKtmUNKkWGNuAIPRAPEXLOaLOLONhd1W3qJWAawKZqJSQjwGvrf7M43L5sIWHckETB@jU9DCQci62N8BHHoHesM1YGkVXjYMsk5ArRCeWEBySTfoobWIatTgBMw3e5aKxsqTX8GT@Hdo4/C0r/m5Vdt1uhxsYSZbA56uhQesktZ5MeC/WH3ZJ24IZJ35ZAVqnVFbbGMN4qoIDYe7vGos19KhEr2k5tDeLlCwfhjWhYFOaH3MdSGT8lYFVRNYXuIwk2pfKmGyZpk7IHOLZOG8YgEPhrj4IGliP2vUsXabblTdLkJHos29pna7oczafu0UYI8Nb5ypo5Yb5i/LQu2@jgnR6wmDOtogypOQLzElY2gZ2yO66UZ9t8X1FNHQ9zMVS77Yc@x/6TCIDSAUDuMpD5SXPt8cqlFYqofsOnudiiauvqMuDt2oS89S5gjpV3ctOo1ox1a9bq8Qcqrd2cDCannewIOzxoPY100szDa45hAmMJWQANQgmzJkYF3DJQ9Bg26X9EmiqGSubrRgtKyd/jffJebNZmK2vyu0vVnoH8RmzSFxdaAx3/RyIGkXrAes29MsExao78E56/bgjPVMsP@D6D1IjzVsECCU1u2rEU9RTkT7Q09y7XNqV5yA@G@uHgiaJFfgjkAJFksMfMcrwzTOY6tg2Rx66CQtk4w9hI/AGxvP4U5axndxDjKLeRZnZRLiLQJO8pw9xGwa3scAlIoQXrJZmC0hfB5f4yh6d4uMAxXERLFMS/zRgBbXCU9BuiZGLblCmSmnISvqUd/LSO9lQzRsr4by6H4eplgbH8HrbJzGY3ZTmX2jtTzhN9GYGYtUzgxRWber3jnBGxLqGKY/6zy4R8G6Uvgw6dXyYlDPivvMPPx75jFA0b784a3NBGCf1RpFGnSZkQ1RhyckVcn1RR1A7FYA1cbogoZwKDG05uN5n83iWbTAMMvY8Gb//3Vl@Be4MlSubG3wJZC@SFf2X2ZfrLrBZJzeZzWArxG@KqBbm@ysXrR7KvOYCrR57Sr9oS@basO@KSlTiZb/@t/IyxxkqNHyA6tvomtt7io2qLJuffqHLzKqt61uMohr1G4zOhUSBjWOgpq0kSZRAhGdjhYTJn8G98SvXmajWfOOmb2LFDupd@0INeT3/f6OQcuxuDIERofVMQvQ@h0pkxcPV5@FnVpDeymIXlE6WC15/qaSt8N1H@Br6V0a/JOGCA3DJ25FpJt/3Q6ZvZEPHuKqnR42SdQgiPgXk/QgREeeBFh9HE9CSJLgmeowkwwmkzH9iBRGJZQpazuysOfEEc5euMWiMl0DoRuUPyTMwiTDZpWF@V3kklLHge/3HH@uovsl/h/H9sia@jXu@dsU/5vwBw)

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 180 bytes

```
>+[++[++>]<<+]>+[->>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+<<<<<<<<<<]-[>+<-------]>->-------->>++++++>+++>--------------------->+++>>>------->,[>+<,]>[-<<[[->+<]<]>>.>>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>]>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1BCsMwDAS/4ruivkDsR8we3JRQkzSHkpDnu1ZSG9qRQFotku7vlNdpH@dSIFE8QTNhVQrIf1iHGqvUC0LxbX3rxEsf/nA6aB4GPzQQUc1i/SpGI3BDw42G9CkIljLnZQnP/AppC490rB8)

Can likely be golfed quite a bit more, as the majority of the code is setting up the string "HdlroWolle" on the tape.

Explanation:

```
>+[++[++>]<<+]>+                          108 = 'l'
[->>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+<<<<<<<<<<]          ptr before '\0lllllllll'

-[>+<-------]>-                           ptr on 'H'

>--------                                 'd'
>                                         'l'
>++++++                                   'r'
>+++                                      'o'
>---------------------                    'W'
>+++                                      'o'
>                                         'l'
>                                         'l'
>-------                                  'e'    ("HdlroWolle")

> ,[>+<,]         [Read all input, counting the length of it 2 cells after the string.]

>[-<                                      Do len(input) times: 

<[                                        Shift the string right by 1
    [->+<]
    <
]
[see https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/50443/brainfuck-part-2---working-with-arrays]

[Print the first character of the string and move the far 
 right cell back to the beginning, rotating the string.]
>>.>>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>]

>]                                        End loop
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```hs
($cycle "HelloWorld").take.length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxDoAgDADArxDCoAs/YPcHzg0WIVSaQI3h9ZWbL8OoSKQPlBZKE@wQxY3Mn0@awubijITGHivxyZ0uu3uBip6w3ZJVVzXQ0Ux@fw)

Comment: xnor has written a 3 bytes lesser answer, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `sequences.repeating`, 33 bytes

```factor
[ "HelloWorld"swap length cycle ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcsxDsIwDAXQvaf4ygF6ADgAdGFBiAExWKnbRjVOcIyqnj6wsb3lTRQ9W7tdh8vpgJVNWVD5/WGNXP/qjQuTJ51RjN33Ykkdx64LaxLBkl4gx0ibhvZAOLNIvmeTMdSNCoR19gVxj8J4tki/07cv)

Answer (score 2):

## [lin](https://github.com/molarmanful/lin), 25 bytes

```
"HelloWorld"`cyc.~ len `t
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-lin) Returns an iterator.

For testing purposes:

```
"how are you" ; `_` outln
"HelloWorld"`cyc.~ len `t
```

### Explanation

Cycle and take (input length) items.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“ ⁷ỴNt»ṁ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of characters and yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//4oCcIOKBt@G7tE50wrvhuYH///8naG93IGFyZSB5b3Un)**

#### How?

Pretty simple...

```
“ ⁷ỴNt»ṁ - Link: list of characters, S
“ ⁷ỴNt»  - dictionary lookup -> "HelloWorld"
       ṁ - mould like S
```

Answer (score 2):

## vim, 46 bytes

```
$mma<C-R>=col('$')
aHelloWorld<C-V><ESC><ESC>`mlDo<ESC>@"khjllDkdd
```

### Annotated

```
$mm                      # Go to the end of input and mark our position
a                        # Append...
  <C-R>=col('$')         #   The column offset/line length
  aHelloWorld<C-V><ESC>  #   This exact string
<ESC>                    # ...which yields a command that prints "HelloWorld"
                         # once per char in the original input. (All that matters
                         # is that this string is at least as long as the output 
                         # needs to be.)

`mlD                     # Delete the string we just appended, copying into register "
o<ESC>@"                 # Run the command, putting a bunch of "HelloWorld"s on next line
khjllD                   # Make the new line the same length as the input
kdd                      # delete the input
```

`<C-R>` is 0x12, `<ESC>` is 0x1b, `<C-V>` is 0x16.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/XyU3N1HINjk/R0NdRV2TK9EjNScnPzy/KCdFTFo6ITfHJV/aQSk7IysnxyU7JQWi3sZZN8gOrgfI87VD0gfkh9nZuAY7QwiwGWAWkjkA)

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/38XBNieV00FJkyvTIzUnJz88vygnRdrBlqsmx@X//4z8coXEolSFyvxSAA "V (vim) – Try It Online") for 28 bytes

Comment: @AaroneousMiller That isn't so much an improvement on mine as just a significantly better approach. You should make it an answer of your own.

Comment: fair enough, will do

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 37 bytes

```powershell
-join($args|%{'HelloWorld'[$i++%10]})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BjoIwEIbvfYo5lC1ETNwHMCExMd7W6MGDMYaFEeqWVtuyaJBnZwuoq3OazPfN385JVahNjkK09ABTqNvxUXHp01hn5ubVbOGQ2igtUralfDTyPie7JmgbQiKfhD7LVQWxRriqkoUv9oIFPdYcJeaV/H2jA/zhQkDOC4gtpHEl3wP6zokB3MCDmoAraqzmMguB4uWEicXU/ZnuB6bRlMK6wYc7JRrMnmyX61lprCq@vo9uaRcNYV2tyyRBY7qU@/oYz//pT2/1yL5rTzDXqujGL881pGn/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org) (full program), 145 bytes

The full program rule doubles the length.

```
fn main(){for l in std::io::stdin().lines(){print!("{}",(0..).zip(l.unwrap().chars()).map(|i|b"HelloWorld"[i.0%10]as char).collect::<String>())}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY69CsIwFIVfJRaEFDXUTYI4uzs4iENsEs1Pk5KkCLZ9CGeXDvpQvo231Oncw_nO5bzeoYlpGD5NkqvN9ykdqphyOG-lD8gi5VBMnFLlKYVjTIhVTkQg6qBcmuGs7bMlLgjJyUPV2JLG3QOrASxvLACYkwpsp7pLthfW-qMPlmcnRYr5ujiziEYOaG-tKBOl20OCz9cdNPt-GvbfN3wX0XCpDZokIqONRiZyLY0GJ0blECcR5NT5AQ)

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org) (function), 85 bytes

```
|l:&str|(0..).zip(l.chars()).map(|i|b"HelloWorld"[i.0%10]as char).collect::<String>()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU47TgMxFOx9isdKRLYAa-mQA9T0KEqBKJa1HWy_2Cvbq0jJ7kloUsABOE5ug60Vr5k3mo_m6zuOKZ9_tYd9ZzxlcEKVQT_9jFnfPVw2E4pVynGiLeeMH81AkfefXUyUMb7vBjqZ6aN5UYhhGyLK5s3w9vq-fe8SVB_jfUBUfRbi8TVH43fPlP2XrwnRIQIar8B4SFkKYYIQ5albeBVS3USg3lDiGf0VbU5zcwuarqqBj_4QyxDG2JrMZF7Kz5eb5KS2DhZI4Kyz4JK02tnCVEVZ5KyiXjJ_)

Comment: Using `Iterator::cycle`, you can save 6 bytes: `|l:&[_]|b"HelloWorld".iter().copied().cycle().take(l.len()).collect::<Vec<_>>()`

Comment: @corvus_192 Nice find, since it has basically nothing in common with my answer feel free to post it seperately

Answer (score 2):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 54 bytes

```
/ H l o o l " \w>?hn$vihn$@?]oK
 " e l W r d !  ^(H' <
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/19fwUMhRyEfCHMUlBRiyu3sM/JUyjKBhIN9bL43F1AwFSgVrlCkkKKgqKAQp@GhrmDz/392Zk6OQkZmrkJiiUJKYnkeAA)

## Flattened

```
/"HelloWorld"!\w>?hn$vihn$@?]oK
                ^(H' <
/"HelloWorld"!\                  Pushes the hello world string on the tape
               w      ihn$@   K  While where are characters to read on the input
                >?hn$v           If the tape is outside of "HelloWorld"
                ^(H' <           Rewind the tape
                           ?]o   Print one character from the tape and move to the next one
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>37</s>, 35 bytes

```ruby
->x{('HelloWorld'*l=x.size)[0...l]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iWkPdIzUnJz88vygnRV0rx7ZCrzizKlUz2kBPTy8ntvZ/QVFmXolCml5yYk6OhnpGfrlCYlGqQmV@qbrmfwA)

-2 bytes thanks to @Steffan

Comment: 35: `->x{('HelloWorld'*l=x.size)[0...l]}`

Comment: @Steffan nice catch! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 26 bytes

```
<<<${(r:$#1::HelloWorld:)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuha7bGxsVKo1iqxUlA2trDxSc3Lyw_OLclKsNGshCqDqtkUrFZanFpVUlmbmFyQWp6SlZ2RlK8VCZQE)

Answer (score 2):

## x86‑64 machine code on Linux, 97 B

### input

- `/dev/stdin` connected to a pipe or terminal in cooked mode
- possibly empty input
- Linux zeros processor registers upon process initialization (with the obvious exception of `rsp`).

### source code

Uses NASM – the Netwide Assembler.
Overview of algorithm:

1. Infinitely wait until data become available. (`select`)
2. Query total number of Bytes immediately available for reading. (`FIONREAD`)
3. Discard input. (`TCIFLUSH`)
4. Integer division: Bytes that were available for reading count divided by 10.
5. Loop: Whole 10 Byte writes of `'HelloWorld'`.
6. Write remainder of integer division Bytes.

```
global _start

bits 64
default rel

; These two constants rather serve as documentation:
STDIN_FILENO         equ   0
STDOUT_FILENO        equ   1
; Linux (`syscall`) system call numbers used in this program:
sys_exit             equ   60
sys_ioctl            equ   16
sys_select           equ   23
sys_write            equ   1
; `ioctl(2)` requests used:
FIONREAD             equ   0x0000541B
TCFLSH               equ   0x0000540B
; Argument to `TCFLSH` request:
TCIFLUSH             equ   0


; ==============================================================
section .text
hello_world:
    db 'Hello'
    db 'World'
; 'HelloWorld'’s length is `10`, but this is cleaner style:
hello_world_length   equ   $ - hello_world

_start:
    ; rax    rdi  rsi    rdx   r10   r8
    ; select(  1, [rsp], NULL, NULL, NULL)
    push 1                      ; bitfield with LSB set
    mov rsi, rsp                ; *readfds
    pop rdi                     ; nfds
    push rdi                    ; rsp for get_iteration_count
    mov al, sys_select
    syscall
    
get_input_length:
    ; rax   rdi           rsi       rdx
    ; ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, FIONREAD, [rsp])
    
    xor edi, edi                ; fd := 0 (STDIN_FILENO)
    xchg rsi, rdx               ; bytes available buffer
    mov si, FIONREAD            ; ioctl(2) request number
    mov al, sys_ioctl
    syscall
    
discard_input:
    ; rax   rdi           rsi     rdx
    ; ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TCFLSH, TCIFLUSH)
    
    mov edx, edi                ; TCIFLUSH = 0 → copy zero
    mov sil, TCFLSH & 0xFF      ; TCFLSH − 0x10 = FIONREAD
    mov al, sys_ioctl
    syscall
    ; `rax` may be non-zero now, in particular −ENOTTY.
    test eax, eax               ; for dumb last char = "\n" test
    setns dil                   ; subtrahend = 0 for ENOTTY
    
get_iteration_count:
    ; Retrieve number of Bytes that were available for reading.
    pop rax
    sub eax, edi                ; subtract 1 if this is terminal
    jc exit                     ; user typed ^D (detach input)
    
    ; Load divisor.
    push hello_world_length
    pop rcx
    ; eax := number of whole writes; edx := Bytes in partial write
    div ecx
    
    ; Save Bytes in partial write for `finish_write` below.
    ; The `push rdx`/`pop rdx` pattern is just two 2 Bytes.
    push rdx
    
    ; Use `ebx` as loop counter, because `syscall` clobbers `rcx`
    ; and this does not require a REX prefix like r8 – r15 do.
    xchg eax, ebx
write:  
    ; rax   rdi            rsi          rdx
    ; write(STDOUT_FILENO, hello_world, 10)
    xchg edx, ecx
    lea rsi, [hello_world]
    mov dil, STDOUT_FILENO
    
    test ebx, ebx               ; zero _whole_ writes test
    jz finish_write             ; zero entire 10B writes
keep_writing:
    mov al, sys_write
    syscall
    dec ebx
    jnz keep_writing
    
    ; Write the remainining ≤ 9 Bytes.
finish_write:
    pop rdx
    mov al, sys_write
    syscall

exit:
    xchg ebx, edi               ; rdi := 0 (= “successful”)
    push sys_exit               ; need to wipe entire register
    pop rax                     ; because we may have jumped
    syscall                     ; here from get_iteration_count

; vim: ft=nasm:
```

### disassembly

```
helloWorld.o:     file format ELF64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <hello_world>:
   0:   48                      rex.W
   1:   65 6C                   gs ins byte ptr es:[rdi], dx
   3:   6C                      ins    byte ptr es:[rdi], dx
   4:   6F                      outs   dx, dword ptr ds:[rsi]
   5:   57                      push   rdi
   6:   6F                      outs   dx, dword ptr ds:[rsi]
   7:   72 6C                   jb     75 <exit + 0x1B>
   9:   64                      fs

000000000000000A <_start>:
   A:   6A 01                   push   0x1
   C:   48 89 E6                mov    rsi, rsp
   F:   5F                      pop    rdi
  10:   57                      push   rdi
  11:   B0 17                   mov    al, 0x17
  13:   0F 05                   syscall 

0000000000000015 <get_input_length>:
  15:   31 FF                   xor    edi, edi
  17:   48 87 F2                xchg   rdx, rsi
  1A:   66 BE 1B 54             mov    si, 0x541B
  1E:   B0 10                   mov    al, 0x10
  20:   0F 05                   syscall 

0000000000000022 <discard_input>:
  22:   89 FA                   mov    edx, edi
  24:   40 B6 0B                mov    sil, 0xB
  27:   B0 10                   mov    al, 0x10
  29:   0F 05                   syscall 
  2B:   85 C0                   test   eax, eax
  2D:   40 0F 99 C7             setns  dil

0000000000000031 <get_iteration_count>:
  31:   58                      pop    rax
  32:   29 F8                   sub    eax, edi
  34:   72 24                   jb     5A <exit>
  36:   6A 0A                   push   0xA
  38:   59                      pop    rcx
  39:   F7 F1                   div    ecx
  3B:   52                      push   rdx
  3C:   93                      xchg   ebx, eax

000000000000003D <write>:
  3D:   87 D1                   xchg   ecx, edx
  3F:   48 8D 35 BA FF FF FF    lea    rsi, [rip + 0XFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBA]
  46:   40 B7 01                mov    dil, 0x1
  49:   85 DB                   test   ebx, ebx
  4B:   74 08                   je     55 <finish_write>

000000000000004D <keep_writing>:
  4D:   B0 01                   mov    al, 0x1
  4F:   0F 05                   syscall 
  51:   FF CB                   dec    ebx
  53:   75 F8                   jne    4D <keep_writing>

0000000000000055 <finish_write>:
  55:   5A                      pop    rdx
  56:   B0 01                   mov    al, 0x1
  58:   0F 05                   syscall 

000000000000005A <exit>:
  5A:   87 DF                   xchg   edi, ebx
  5C:   6A 3C                   push   0x3C
  5E:   58                      pop    rax
  5F:   0F 05                   syscall
```

Having the `'HelloWorld'` string in the `.text` section is weird, but putting (read-only) data into an already/definitely existing section, i. e. `.text`, makes the executable file smaller.
The stripped ELF64 executable file has a size of merely 440 B, not that *that* really mattered for *code* golfing.

### output

- output lacks of a trailing newline
- `HelloWorld` repeating until the input’s length is reached
- on a terminal *input length − 1* accounting for a presumed terminating `"\n"` [even if the user actually detached from input `Ctrl‑D`]

### limitations

- I am *not sure*, but *maybe* the `FIONREAD` `ioctl(2)` I am utilizing is capped at `0x7FFFF000` because *one* `read(2)` can transfer at most this many Bytes? Therefore this program’s output will be limited to 2,147,479,552 Bytes accordingly.
- At any rate, there’s a 32-bit `div ecx`, so a string length ≥ 2<sup>32</sup> is not handled correctly.
- If we’re reading from a pipe, the pipe’s capacity may be the limiting factor. In `pipe(7)`, § pipe capacity, it says the default value is 65536 B (so it can be changed). Similarly, a terminal’s input buffer may have comparable “low” dimensions. Yet these are implementation details *outside* of this program.

Answer (score 1):

## [simply](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/simply), <del>111</del> 106 bytes

This is (yet another) language I'm just working on, for fun.

It is a very verbose language, and still in progress, which is why the algorithm is ... less conventional and very convoluted...

```
def&f($v){$C=&str_chunk("HelloWorld"&len($v));send$C[0];}echo&join(&array_map(&str_chunk($argv[0]10)&f)'')
```

Due to oversights in the parser, the values don't have to have to be separated by commas.

---

### Ungolfed:

```
Create a function called &handle_chunk with arguments ($value).
Begin
    Assign $len the value of executing the function &len with argument $value.
    
    Set the variable $chunks with the value of calling the function &str_chunk with the arguments "HelloWorld", $len.
    
    Return the value $chunks[0].
End.

Display the result of calling &join(
    Call the function &array_map with the arguments (
        Run &str_chunk($argv[0], 10),
        &handle_chunk
    ),
    ""
).
```

Should be self-explanatory.

---

### How to run:

Download the repository and open `índex.html`.

---

---

### Unintended method:

This is simply a re-implementation of [m90's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250523):

```
%c="";def&f($s)call%c->padEnd(&len($s)"HelloWorld");
```

Works the same way as the intended way.

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 15 bytes

```
"HelloWorld"⥊˜≢
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=UmVwZWF0SGVsbG9Xb3JsZCDihpAgIkhlbGxvV29ybGQi4qWKy5ziiaIKUmVwZWF0SGVsbG9Xb3JsZCAiVGhlIHJhaW4gaW4gU3BhaW4gZmFsbHMgbWFpbmx5IG9uIHRoZSBwbGFpbiI=)

```
"HelloWorld"⥊˜≢
               ≢    # get the shape (length) of the input
            ⥊˜      # and use this to reshape
"HelloWorld"        # the string "HelloWorld"
                    # (recycling elements if required)
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Kustom](https://help.kustom.rocks/s1-general/knowledgebase/top/c2-functions), 39 bytes

Basically just [this Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250523/112863).

The extra byte is for the global variable name.

```
$tc(rpad,"",tc(len,gv(i)),HelloWorld)$
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 35 bytes

```powershell
% L*h|%{'HelloWorld'*$_|% S*g 0,$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcw9DsIwDAbQq3xDI0tRkThGBzYGxiqiFo4wMTI/UUU4eyjjW97dKvtDWHV3NudOYhXJGau9aASJZy4stbz/umZVSL4hPbGkWgitBxyitPChaUvsZK4LxWFuAcd4wX4c5m/vPw)

## Windows PowerShell, 38 bytes

```powershell
% L*h|%{'HelloWorld'*$_|% S*g -a 0,$_}
```

Same as above, but PS 5.1 requires actually naming the parameter "-ArgumentList" (shortened to "-a") for the Substring() method call.

Input comes from the pipeline.

Nothing fancy; this is basically
`ForEach-Object {$l = $_.Length; ('HelloWorld' * $l).Substring(0, $l)}`
The expensive method calls can be golfed by using the cmdlet ForEach-Object (that is, its alias "%"), and its possibility to call a method of the input object by name, accepting wildcards.

```powershell
% L*h|%{'HelloWorld'*$_|% S*g 0,$_}
% L*h                                  # "ForEach-Object -MemberName Length": invoke the method "Length" for the string passed in the pipeline
     |                                 # Pipe the length of the input string to the next cmdlet
      %{                               # "ForEach-Object -ScriptBlock {"
        'HelloWorld'*$_                #     repeat the string 'HelloWorld' <Length> times
                       |               #     and pipe the 'HelloWorldHelloWorld...' to the next cmdlet
                        % S*g 0,$_     #     "ForEach-Object -MemberName Substring -ArgumentList 0, <Length>": invoke the method "Substring" for the string passed in the pipeline, get <Length> chars starting at 0
       }                               # }: end of the scriptblock; Output is implicit
```

Comment: It is a code snippet, not a full program (PS script) and not a function. Sorry.

Comment: You repeating _it is a snippet_ doesn't make it so. ForEach-Object is a regular command in Power**Shell**, like grep in bash, so it may be used. This [bash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239647/78395) uses the same method, and nobody was complaining about the byte count; instead, the comments were actually constructive. You have yet to provide one single _argument_ to back up your claim that this is a snippet, or why pipeline input should be counted. So, please, either finally **back up** your claim with something other than repeating _because I say so_, or pass it on to moderation.

Comment: **References:** [Programs may take input via STDIN](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2448/78395), [Functions may take input via the same methods as full programs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2455/78395), [Programs may combine two or more input methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5415/78395).

Comment: if you use a bash pipe then you can't to use `ForEach` simple. Your code `'how are you', 'hrienehwnv', 'kill him at dawn' |` is a Powershell code, that placed outside counted bytes. Please, use bash pipe correcly or place `|` into counted bytes.

Comment: That pipe is the initial invocation, and I'm using it quite correctly; pipeline input is explicitly allowed, see above, and that's how you do it in a **Shell**. You don't count the function invocation `&$f` in your script at [PS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250625/78395), either. The bash I linked above uses **exactly the same invocation** of a header `echo "$REPLY" | \ ` followed by the counted code `grep ...`, and nobody, including you, complained. Where's the difference, pray tell? This is just another iteration of "_because I say so_".

Comment: I second @mazzy, I think these constraints exists in order to keep things comparable

Comment: Which "_constraints_"? Fact: Input by pipeline is allowed. Fact: Pipeline input is invoked by using the pipe symbol. Fact: The code's invocation is not counted. Fact: This is not a snippet, as it can run without changes when invoked through the pipeline/stdin. Fact: That first `|` fulfills the _exact same_ function as mazzy's `&$f`. Would one of you, please, **finally** deliver a **documented** reason why the invocation `&$f @string` is "free", but `'how are you'|` isn't? I have provided what I think is pretty hard evidence that my count is OK; something that is utterly missing from mazzy.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) (function), 179 bytes

***Used own logic and avoid system define function***

```php
function fnc($rs,$as){$dr="";$fv=explode(".",strval(strlen($as)/strlen($rs)));while((int)$fv[0]>0){$dr.=$rs;(int)$fv[0]--;}return $dr.=substr($rs,0,(int)strlen($as)%strlen($rs));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NCsIwEITvfYqwREggrb3H6tU38CAeapuSQkhCflpF@uwxBoSedtn5dmastOl0sdJWaYp6CLPRaNIDwc4z3Hv6waPrADielk68rDKjINAA88EtvSJ5KKHJjzz@d@cppXyVsxKEzDrQ/HtvH@e2mDVdBvjuXtd8cyJEp1GRfXxmp1KgZYXbhRz2IXxLvKrEIE2pjOAqlDI349QIDIE0K@qdQG8TIyDK0xc)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 90 bytes

***Sugested by  @Steffan***

```php
function fnc($a){for($f=strlen($a);$f--;)$d.="HelloWorld";return substr($d,0,strlen($a));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYy7DgIhEAB7voKQLSC5M/brxdY/uFqBDUaykAUq47fjo7GdzExNdZ7ONVU1abDv98Ka2Fu4uicVsUBb65IjfwkCrSs6CIfNXGLOZS@Sg0GJfQjrNm4f10JYjss/cviaqFT0qfzO2tCjBTLa4XwD)

Comment: You can just use the function name `f`, no need for a longer one to save 2 bytes.

Comment: PHP will automatically cast strings to numbers, so all of your `(int)`s can be removed.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I'll try that. its already 02:10 am. feeling sleepy ;)

Comment: also, I don't think it's allowed to take the `HelloWorld` as input. But here's [90 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYy7CgIxEAD7fMUSUiRwJ/brYesfWJ95ECHshr2EQ8Rvj4/GdpiZmus4nWuuaqROvt2ZIJG3ZnXPxGJNWrYmJdKXoEnzjM6Ew6IvsRS@spSgUWLrQrD128e1JkzH6R85fA1UKvrMvzPozDusEuHBvWtwON4 "PHP – Try It Online"), or [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYoxDoQgEAB7XrEhFJBY2Ct3rT@wNKhLKDbuBiXG1yOxmGZmJEkd/5JEmehrPKwJzv/Osp5Xto0lo2C4rJ6QiGfOtOvOkG@J8Ltd1zfh6qAUbonBRAs68Q0hIzxcigY31Bc "PHP – Try It Online") with `str_repeat`.

Comment: Actually, the rules say we have to use a full program, for some reason. That's also 59 bytes, tho: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkU5Mz8hWKS5OKS4o0gDi@KLUgNbFEQ8kjNScnPzy/KCdFSUclxxYolZOap5GQkpKgqaljABTStP7/PyO/XCGxKFWhMr@0FAA "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: @Steffan In codegolf, can we compromise anything to save the bytes??. I know str_repeat can do this in short way. i tried to avoid that and tried my own login. :)

Comment: What do you mean "compromise anything to save the bytes"?

Comment: I mean, to save bytes, can use var name to just one char and anything that can be possible?

Comment: yes i know it not allowed to take hello world, I just make it in a way you can replace HelloWorld with "Steffan" and "BlaBla"

Comment: the function given by me is still using the long `fnc` name (and so is the other). Also, your original one can be golfed by using one-character names

Answer (score 1):

## R (function), 41 bytes

```
`substr<-`(a,1,90,strrep("HelloWorld",9))
```

I assume this can be improved...

This takes advantage of a feature of `substr()` I learned when I was today years old: `substr()` has a replacement function, and if the string replacing the substring is longer than the substring, it is cut off at the appropriate place, which works perfectly for this challenge. We can replace the entire input string `a` with a string of concatenated `"HelloWorld"`s with the last one truncated. This will not work for any string longer than 90 characters but no test cases in the input are that long. To make it work for longer strings, you can replace both of the `90` and `9` with `nchar(a)`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdBCsMgEADAryy5qLCB9hjIA/qDXrNNFKVblVUjeb1t5zYyHKwzuBb3GlLUZMZW2qtUWedNE95xueFvYrOeHpY5PZPwMeFizCiUM19618qnDiQWrtQUgvISbLS@x/O/d2AGHz5AFQ7qURkEZ8YX)

Comment: Nice answer!  To compete fairly with everyone else, you'll need to include *all* the essential code required for the function definition in the byte-count: this includes the ```function(a)``` bit [like this](https://tio.run/##FcdBCsMgEADAryy5qLCB9hjIA/qDXrNNFKVblVUjeb1t5zYyHKzzcC3uNaSoyWylvUqVdd404R2XG/4mNuvpYZnTMwkfEy7GjEI586V3rXzqQGLhSk0hKC/BRut7PP97B2bw4QNU4aAelUFwZnwB), which makes this 52 bytes in total...

Comment: Also, although none of the examples given include >90 character strings, it isn't really valid to assume that this will always be the case, so you'll need to include the ```nchar(a)``` (or something equivalent) to fully comply with the spec.  Luckily you can [re-arrange a bit](https://tio.run/##FcdBCsMgEEDRqwzZOIKFHqDZ9wZdW6MomY4yak1Ob9PFf/BlBnjcZujsWsqMh@GVXbSCh9a1v2sTvBJfcHl6ovzKQttiWJv7xay2FDrRoYp5gBUPZ@7KgIqSPPs4@Pu/PRFBTB@wDTY7WGkDQc8f) to avoid doing this twice...

Comment: BTW - you can easily convert to a full program using ```scan()``` instead of defining a function, although it costs a byte: [Try it](https://tio.run/##DccxCsMwDEDRvacQWWSDh@4he2/QWU0EMlXlIid1cnrXw3/wvfdzqStZSIhxtsVWIQ9nnOvxqruHkfM3TA9WLc/iuk3JYroPOkppQM5wlQNvKJ7ZWJr9xryzKkj@AO2wUTPsfw)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks for the tips. I will correct this later today!

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 15 bytes

```
'HelloWorld'$~#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYpBCsIwFET3nmJQ6W/BBtct1oIgLly5cV3a1KTGfIypxY1XjyUHcGAevGGGsBTUY1eANtiimJsLHC7nY6CTNIav7ExH6@8qZAvfxqPiCY2T@PBIKGd3WlqpJvuOetfGQOkHGo@umWwcI/Y0Q/wJLWSruE4JeV6BkoG1fXmn7a1Oy@Q5spdZnyWigm/DDw)

Very straightforward.

### Explanation

```
'HelloWorld'$~#
            $~     reshape
'HelloWorld'       this string
              #    by the length of the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C#](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform) (function), 38 bytes

```cs
x=>x.Select((_,i)=>"HelloWorld"[i%10])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLasMwEDxXX7EYChakpj079iWkTaGFQg45hFAUeRMvlaVEjzwI@XZXrkmTVhdpVsPM7Ej3II3FNjjSa5genccmZ7coGxmlUHoy2mUvqNGS/Md4I73NGZNKOAcf1qytaODEIJ5NWCqS4Lzw8doZquBdkE55/Gd3z0HLofM2ag3gdaxDg1YsFQ5lLWxZwgqK9lCUh2yKXYQ0/RwQL8pkgkqZmbGqSuZ0//S44G3Oep35AkhvgocCTpDUZg/CIhxNSAYRWooL1Hu969AXKQU1NSA8VGKvu1kC5xslPGyiLVa92NV10lFvQvxB/etXjI1icUZhNrPkMVaF6U/Ay04OihJ6x1i1lsKnq9RxziNhG1BLHG@DUOklC@c5O5/bbw)

---

## [C#](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform) (full program), <s>102</s> 96 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to [TKirishima](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/112099/tkirishima)

```cs
using System.Linq;System.Console.WriteLine(args[0].Select((_,i)=>"HelloWorld"[i%10]).ToArray());
```

This is a complete program in C#10 thanks to [implicit top-level statements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements). TIO doesn't support this, but [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JsOHIl) does.

Comment: `using System.Linq;System.Console.WriteLine("aertyha".Select((_,i)=>"HelloWorld"[i%10]).ToArray());`

Answer (score 1):

## Regex (Boost), 76 bytes

```
s/(.(.(.(.(.(.(.(.(.(.)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?/?1H?2e?3l?4l?5o?6W?7o?8r?9l?10d/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVVtb6NGEP7Or5i4VQ02SezkcpcDE6RKlVrpdB/6orZqWrSGBVZZdtEuxHFi30@vO7vYDnbOBQRmZp5nH2Zmx2ldnxdpuvmGiZS3GYXZXErdXCpa0KeLsq7vnLQkCpL6r78hgp8H3y8WD/Pr9s/l8o9fy/eL0t3oS/fi7enFb8/LePpjfEXjax6/4/GNjN//Hn@Q8a2KP/J4Oskui413zD/wYVRHSR06rxIZKlSUVHcOEw3UCu8JVUoqN5VCN2AVjyqqNSmo96KbLAhSDIDZDLZW89Paqch4CIo2rRIwDddgKPVSNORpy@m9bL39hQa/2BCwbwMvXHdpyihnVTQJAbPIkUoRUVDXuoRvH6R7zPesLZLeJo0rzokHs2j/Psf3He0oZyJLLHlHNtIevDiARy4VuGGox@OdxRwsB/fMBG0X@fzbp0/h3ku5pjZkpKNoeH8/RGiHGI@PMOuvg6yUfaTuqNfO2hakIky4OzUWMR7XZ9FQD1erM7dLkTF5rwQH@Q4tyMbNJqvVLovW4L@79W9uvSPr6vrK//jBn17doAd7Iy2xQt@63mh8MbuL/xn4nd79egeV/Ek8Es6yrnasoaacgPK6j9qmG3u/V4N6q/FMn/yEEVYEczsZ9mnyQxq9o8lP0@QHNKY5rq@SBiQy2Z0aBHarBoGQSSWzpAqBtI0E3YvAHqlIk@RM6SaRgi9hdeQinIe9dsJlsV73YhhCbhpLL1iTlljIfFfWlGA3DNkwAJSyiuBIDDP@sGucOW7Vh7CH0qdQRr8@hXr6P9TTKVTVob6L4MupdH0FVSBKH6DepDDsozKak5Y3ARyMmsEPpooB7Bos56SAgfFgI5yaP50KO8b6gjHCrX2Q2BIWhk3ORIETpm6bXuXM9ns288cGFbThTFC3U8WE38V74fGoePYA7aZHXVN1XOQ5mr7Oiw4v28ao7qtKFK05SalreX0U6YPGC2VuJ4K5bz9uEjrrTSkXQBSFpWydUjEqaLkQj84D4xxKVgFpICML4TjEIXO8UqcWtK2kkJhfRSqWKqlTWbNUM85S@Sh5SoTEhOGfAtP/pibJenPOrczEqvwP)

This is a single regex substitution, to be applied once.

It uses nested conditional replacement. The number of capture groups that get set is the number of characters matched, and they will always be consecutively numbered starting at 1.

It will start by matching the full 10 character length as many times as possible, which will be replaced each time with the full `HelloWorld` string. Then when it reaches a point where there are fewer than 10 characters remaining, it will do its last replacement.

## Regex (PCRE2), 116

`s/(.(.(.(.(.(.(.(.(.(.)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?/${1:+H${2:+e${3:+l${4:+l${5:+o${6:+W${7:+o${8:+r${9:+l${10:+d}}}}}}}}}}/g`

[Try it on regex101!](https://regex101.com/r/nn2PPX/1)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVd7U@JIEP@fTzG6lCQkiuK66xJxCyEqd@FRIbnVXXdTIQwwZUhSeSwq8NXP60weJDz2ggWZnv5193T3dLeG4xxPDOP9wwiPiYVRvymLVa3Za4ma2m0r2rd2S7lHl4UPxDLMYITRlWO4uHoyvS4YU91FmvPjJ6oj@fBmPn8engePr68PyvTTfMq8exXmZPvDft3@VIqLsxp3X1xUaxwuLs5rnFlcfKTfFzXOLi4@1bhvxcVn@n5Z49zi4gvdPTutcaNV@lQm7@ymHYc8Kjt1zREyR/D8EbHDI2RJLrEmeRqxgYr12TbfdYFYPnLg1dew69ouY9iW5yPqkvIMe54@wewC9NRqBjCgqysUU8NXSsfWyBSQi/3AtdCZsEKhSO/V8vWXWCa7iHezig4HlAXR1SErrLZMCdeGPcIsWhQQPNSoWPuP6sWnnwIlkzFiaCy1CY6hWszFhHAeMVEyqM37hnxZZuNNHnnkDdtjJjkmqiSUDD/LslRL@OTccEiZIvNr6HCvZyg69U5hFaXbCJtkVj8V0NC2TfCYq1uhueGWxdMfPfoZps4LwB@Xms9YxzqLrurpeghrIRZbhtwfaVR4JKzsJd4b2y5iBMHjuISSOO8gZIqVdFVJEtJdbHqYspS9er309FQCaITguA3MajeImpJyepHoVSEK9kwnFpNYQxEc5xzUS15puTxgIheFJHYtIJdWAgVRvqvT5TLxIiXwHy/5i0t2g7o8r/JfPvNn1QvYgStgTCERiwxb5k6urr/@OuQje1N9uYRtW791k4yi2BEfh1mLwDxhnZ1lD2pIJgZObOOBt/cIZYgI@Pa0lBUzzovxEjHj/WLGOTFhcpxXNR/Z9VNIdBvkRUk9UG8GSltRFVETHxSx2xJbaLm9p3YHoqKJnb7yKGTSB9RAfJ6skoDGYSJ5c@IbUwjcOL2kOkS/NCnVQqXLHVrvpN5NQxKAdQg16VnIoBqAQhlUo9u878liS0CZZwslbqIkqfctMl1rSo3BYK0LVSrICDzfnqFjpJumPUdQ9XVrhH78@olM8oyR2Ow0BoZLHD@j4mFLhaLdDNSHHYblVGBLH5oYPQXoSaVqwIsGHqHq8YhMiI@eXjJKmjuUNNtyU@3cSmKiaocSYqHKDM1opfv19B2kWXCzICwZ2WRDdrMxECUxcs1@z7Y2UK2eJDVkDZKm15UehT0obwulQEhymnag/tpEqf1uoyP@j4UvG6gkpf@M6m6gOg2leR@n/E2j@bcs3gq7PN3tN@88pBv@H1JltilblZS21O6Kwp8ssjZQ3Z7WUJUexKmvqHKM3UIFGyi12U/vsqrc7kGpm6junSyKrcd9PoOBSg9Mv7bR/sSo8SVFcWzqk6gLQvHaNxpQeVGvDjszKrtYiNc0Y4Fq@fjFh9EjuxToSOFiD8zgo44rJIWl/V2klPHYw7BpB76JrYk/FVCmiZdD@jAYJ80YqmFixcwhJmbijj/oKzLr8DH0uyj3NEWUO@1uQxFbIJxHR1R7/BvrPGXXg8iBi3c2D/od8@WPWt/lAA1Iuo@ZRDT1ZjSygS@cwM8U5dA3b@EoQZlgBjJh/mWiYBGLj/hZIdv1Uy@Bdrp9Eg4@0Aar3Nm6@1PpaSMh9a1S3vtHlG/DYiuJ3TvlXsjpiPWA10FJdqIqswxBX8ELUH8NJjWFRTVwXEoEXCaaLCvkBEe5kPrOC4aeT/wAPOau5z0azeh4hgbOY1g@d1qIHBAQB52KvuYikJfi7c@J2NSjta15U8OsiM29rkOuZK9Wloego6PkXAdpPZPlngzVoCN2evLjzsyKIDuUHpBEF8TudL2/Kuww7WqXaeH@G4vAY@FUwoR9HyaNt3o2R@YuTELbAePRGR8mpB2mHhq7OOFhkxFwXQrymU95cyRWyNSMaB9uWVpX4Gir9ym0ch0u9qsdFKYuwRaezq3fhWdimmhKZkj30UifW4WCXtCH8GcUHAsHM9uy4fSuPiOGa3uG7RDDIyYx7N@2CX3UBgvgnyfi/WuE9c17PzapJceX/wE)

PCRE2's conditional replacement syntax is quite a bit more verbose. But you can run this on regex101 and see it work in real time as you type (make sure to erase the test cases first, so it's as fast as possible).

Answer (score 1):

****Swift**, 137 bytes**

```
 var a = readLine()!,h = "HelloWorld",c = h.count,j = a.count,i = Int(j/c),s="";for _ in 0..<i {s += h};s += String(Array(h)[0..<j - i*c])
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) `-R`, 30 bytes

```
("HelloWorld"*length)[:length]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/19DySM1Jyc/PL8oJ0VJKyc1L70kQzPaCsKI/f8/I79cIbEoVaEyv/RffkFJZn5e8X/dIAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 19 bytes

```
LF`dlroWolleH`^:N'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/HLSElpyg/PD8nJ9UjIc7KT732////StmZOTkKGZm5CoklCimJ5XlKAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 17 bytes

```
l:“HelloWorld”×¤<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/P8fqUcMcj9ScnPzw/KKclEcNcw9PP7TE5v//jPxyhcSiVIXK/FIA)

Pretty standard approach I think. It's a shame Gaia does not have a reshape to length built-in like BQN/J :(

### Explained

```
l:“HelloWorld”×¤<
l                  # Length of the input
 :                 # push a second copy of that
  “HelloWorld”     # push the string "HelloWorld" to the stack
              ×    # repeat that string by the length of the input
               ¤<  # push the second copy of the length to the top of the stack and get the first n characters of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
î`HÁMWld
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7mBIwU1Xjmxk&input=ImhvdyBhcmUgeW91Ig)

```
î`HÁMWld     :Implicit input of string
î             :Repeat & slice the following to length of input
 `HÁMWld     :  Compressed string "HelloWorld"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 37 bytes

```julia
~=length;!a=("HelloWorld"^(~a))[1:~a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FccxDsIwDADAva9wPSUSS1dQd37AgECyFEMMxkFRStolXw9w2z0WFZrW3tusbPcSDyPNDo@smk4pa8Cra@T9edo3uvRbykAgBg5jqkCZYUsL7gBjFjaO1T7/PUUVoryACgSqhn6An3cWK2puJD@whf4F)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org/), 28 bytes

```
D@=le<Tab>@")
iHelloWorld<Esc>@=
|lD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/38XBNieV00FJkyvTIzUnJz88vygnRdrBlqsmx@X//4z8coXEolSFyvxSAA)

#### Explanation

```
D                   # Delete the input into the @" register
 @=                 # Set @= register to:
   le<Tab>  )       #   The length of:
          @"        #     The @" register
iHelloWorld<Esc>    # Type "HelloWorld" @= times
                @=  #
|                   # Move cursor to position @=
 lD                 # Delete everything after the cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

## [*><>](https://github.com/redstarcoder/go-starfish), 41 bytes

Uses the `-i` flag to initialize the stack with our input value.

```
l1["dlroWolleH"    v
or1-:?!;rl2(?!u20.O>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLErLLM74/z/HMFopJacoPzw/JyfVQ0kBCMq48osMda3sFa2Lcow07BVLjQz0/O3@//@XX1CSmZ9X/F8301Y9oygzNS81ozyvTB0A)

### Explanation

```
l                    Push the length of the stack onto the stack
 1[                  Pop that length value into a new stack
    "dlrowolleh"     Push "HelloWorld" reversed onto the stack
                   v Change IP Direction downward

                   > Change IP direction rightward
o                    Pop a value off the stack, print it as a char
 r                   Reverse the stack, putting the length value on the top of the stack
  1-:                Subtract one from that value
     ?!;             If that value is 0, halt execution
        r            Reverse the stack
         l           Check the length of the stack
          2(         Is it less than two (Do we have more to print, but have run out of our HelloWorld string)
            ?!u      If NOT, ignore instructions until the next O
               20.   If so, jump to [0,2] in the code box, just before pushing HelloWorld onto the stack
                  O  Else, continue onto the >
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 47 bytes

```c
i;f(*s){for(i=0;*s;*s++="HelloWorld"[i++%10]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUzBCsMgFDvXr5AHBa0duNtAeu9h9x26Hlo3h2B9RTdklH67c2whgZCE6IN2k3/kbJVhTeSbwcBsJ1UTC4XooL87hxcM7gaDFaI@ypGrPS@T9YyTjVTWP@n8MsNJjopUSUe9vlkJWnqGHhP1RXPA5KnGdJXAy8p8B8XQP9ZQXgyD2kVo6a/b8wc)

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 19 bytes

```
"HelloWorld"i0(?;{o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8kjNScnPzy/KCdFKdNAw966Ov///@zMnByFjMxchcQShZTE8jwA)

**Explanation**

```
"HelloWorld"         # push the string "HelloWorld"
            i0(?;    # take input, if there isn't more input, exit program
                 {o  # else print the bottom of the stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 35 bytes

I/O as an array of characters.

```javascript
s=>s.map((_,x)=>"HelloWorld"[x%10])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFdCoQgFAbQrYQQKDWXWoA9zw56iCgpa4qbX@j0t3o7ZzWnCYNf9v/HYbRx0jHoKtBmdtnpSnwtM2p4HkVzZ1laFm1@60LFAS6ALTFmOcmGiMQPV2K8TR4colW0YnF9r@IL)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
khỊsØE
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWtoJUUxJUJCJThBcyVDMyU5OEUmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD1ob3clMjBhcmUlMjB5b3UmZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
khỊsØE  # Implicit input
khỊ     # Push "HelloWorld"
   sØE  # Extend/truncate it
        # to the input's length
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 43 bytes

```lua
print(("HelloWorld"):rep(#...):sub(1,#...))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ8kjNScnPzy/KCdFSdOqKLVAQ1lPT0/Tqrg0ScNQB8zW/P//f3ZmTo5CRmauQmKJQkpieR4A)